# Converting a Pandas GroupBy multiindex output from Series back to DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, multi-index

I have a dataframe:

```
   City     Name
0   Seattle    Alice
1   Seattle      Bob
2  Portland  Mallory
3   Seattle  Mallory
4   Seattle      Bob
5  Portland  Mallory
```

I perform the following grouping:

```py
g1 = df1.groupby(["Name", "City"]).count()
```

which when printed looks like:

```
                  City  Name
Name    City
Alice   Seattle      1     1
Bob     Seattle      2     2
Mallory Portland     2     2
        Seattle      1     1
```

But what I want eventually is another DataFrame object that contains all the rows in the GroupBy object. In other words I want to get the following result:

```
                  City  Name
Name    City
Alice   Seattle      1     1
Bob     Seattle      2     2
Mallory Portland     2     2
Mallory Seattle      1     1
```

How do I do it?

Comment: Aside question: which pandas version do you use? If execute first 2 commands I get g1 as `Empty DataFrame` `Columns: []` `Index: [(Alice, Seattle), (Bob, Seattle), (Mallory, Portland), (Mallory, Seattle)]`

Comment: The question's title is misleading with regard to the accepted answer

Comment: @matanster may I ask what you came here looking to know the answer to? We can think about writing a more accurate answer and directing users' attention with a comment under the question.

Comment: @coldspeed This is just a typical issue with SO, question titles are let to diverge significantly from the content of the question and answers. If meta wasn't as hostile that would probably be a useful aspect to raise there.

Comment: @matanster I agree, however I was only curious to know what it is you were actually searching the answer for, such that it led you to here.

Comment: @saveener You are almost there.  You've got a multi-index dataframe coming from "g1 = df1.groupby( [ "Name", "City"] ).count()".   All you need to do next is reset_index to convert it back to a regular dataframe with redundant Name index values for Mallory: Portland and Mallory: Seattle.

Answer (score 699, accepted):

`g1` here *is* a DataFrame. It has a hierarchical index, though:

```
In [19]: type(g1)
Out[19]: pandas.core.frame.DataFrame

In [20]: g1.index
Out[20]: 
MultiIndex([('Alice', 'Seattle'), ('Bob', 'Seattle'), ('Mallory', 'Portland'),
       ('Mallory', 'Seattle')], dtype=object)
```

Perhaps you want something like this?

```
In [21]: g1.add_suffix('_Count').reset_index()
Out[21]: 
      Name      City  City_Count  Name_Count
0    Alice   Seattle           1           1
1      Bob   Seattle           2           2
2  Mallory  Portland           2           2
3  Mallory   Seattle           1           1
```

Or something like:

```
In [36]: DataFrame({'count' : df1.groupby( [ "Name", "City"] ).size()}).reset_index()
Out[36]: 
      Name      City  count
0    Alice   Seattle      1
1      Bob   Seattle      2
2  Mallory  Portland      2
3  Mallory   Seattle      1
```

Comment: You could have used: `df1.groupby( [ "Name", "City"] ).size().to_frame(name = 'count').reset_index()`

Comment: The second example using `.reset_index()` seems to me to be the best way of joining the output you will get from `df.groupby('some_column').apply(your_custom_func)`. This was not intuitive for me.

Comment: Why `add_suffix` though?

Comment: Is this also true in Python 3? I'm finding a groupby function returning the `pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy` object, not `pandas.core.frame.DataFrame`.

Comment: This answer seems irrelevant for latest python and pandas

Comment: `.to_frame()` is what I came here for and was the method I wasn't aware of, and it perfectly answers the question as it is currently worded. In my case, I wanted to keep my MultiIndex but just turn my resulting GroupBy Series into a DataFrame so Jupyter would display it nicely.

Comment: I used the resulting dataframe converted from the groupby in a swarmplot sns.swarmplot(x='my_category', y='my_values', data=new_df)

Comment: Use `as_index=False`. See [answer by @jezrael](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32307259/4682839).

Comment: @NehalJWani that worked for me after hours of searching, thank you.

Comment: Good call @Wes McKinney !!

Comment: @NehalJWani just wanted to say thank you. This is what I've been after for years.

Answer (score 191):

I want to slightly change the answer given by Wes, because version 0.16.2 requires `as_index=False`. If you don't set it, you get an empty dataframe.

[Source](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#aggregation):

> Aggregation functions will not return the groups that you are aggregating over if they are named columns, when `as_index=True`, the default. The grouped columns will be the indices of the returned object.
>
> Passing `as_index=False` will return the groups that you are aggregating over, if they are named columns.
>
> Aggregating functions are ones that reduce the dimension of the returned objects, for example: `mean`, `sum`, `size`, `count`, `std`, `var`, `sem`, `describe`, `first`, `last`, `nth`, `min`, `max`. This is what happens when you do for example `DataFrame.sum()` and get back a `Series`.
>
> nth can act as a reducer or a filter, see [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#groupby-nth).

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({"Name":["Alice", "Bob", "Mallory", "Mallory", "Bob" , "Mallory"],
                    "City":["Seattle","Seattle","Portland","Seattle","Seattle","Portland"]})
print df1
#
#       City     Name
#0   Seattle    Alice
#1   Seattle      Bob
#2  Portland  Mallory
#3   Seattle  Mallory
#4   Seattle      Bob
#5  Portland  Mallory
#
g1 = df1.groupby(["Name", "City"], as_index=False).count()
print g1
#
#                  City  Name
#Name    City
#Alice   Seattle      1     1
#Bob     Seattle      2     2
#Mallory Portland     2     2
#        Seattle      1     1
#
```

EDIT:

In version `0.17.1` and later you can use `subset` in [`count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.count.html) and [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reset_index.html) with parameter `name` in [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html):

```
print df1.groupby(["Name", "City"], as_index=False ).count()
#IndexError: list index out of range

print df1.groupby(["Name", "City"]).count()
#Empty DataFrame
#Columns: []
#Index: [(Alice, Seattle), (Bob, Seattle), (Mallory, Portland), (Mallory, Seattle)]

print df1.groupby(["Name", "City"])[['Name','City']].count()
#                  Name  City
#Name    City                
#Alice   Seattle      1     1
#Bob     Seattle      2     2
#Mallory Portland     2     2
#        Seattle      1     1

print df1.groupby(["Name", "City"]).size().reset_index(name='count')
#      Name      City  count
#0    Alice   Seattle      1
#1      Bob   Seattle      2
#2  Mallory  Portland      2
#3  Mallory   Seattle      1
```

The difference between `count` and `size` is that `size` counts NaN values while `count` does not.

Comment: I think this is the easiest way - a one liner which uses the nice fact that you can name the series column with reset_index: ```df1.groupby( [ "Name", "City"]).size().reset_index(name="count")```

Comment: Is there a reason why `as_index=False' stopped working in latest versions?
I also tried to run `df1.groupby(["Name", "City"], as_index=False ).size()` but it doesn't affect result (probably because result of the grouping is `Series` not `DataFrame`

Comment: I am not sure, but it seems there are only 2 columns and `groupby` by these columns. But I am not sure, because I am not pandas developer.

Answer (score 73):

The key is to use the [reset_index()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) method.

Use:

```
import pandas

df1 = pandas.DataFrame( { 
    "Name" : ["Alice", "Bob", "Mallory", "Mallory", "Bob" , "Mallory"] , 
    "City" : ["Seattle", "Seattle", "Portland", "Seattle", "Seattle", "Portland"] } )

g1 = df1.groupby( [ "Name", "City"] ).count().reset_index()
```

Now you have your new dataframe in *g1*:

[image: result dataframe]

Comment: This works, thanks! Just a clarification, `count()` function counts all distinct values, thus skips duplicates automatically. After that, `reset_index()` does the trick of creating a new dataframe free from duplicates.

Comment: @saveener You are almost there. You've got a multi-index dataframe coming from "g1 = df1.groupby( [ "Name", "City"] ).count()". All you need to do next is reset_index to convert it back to a regular dataframe with redundant Name index values for Mallory: Portland and Mallory: Seattle.   This answer by Ferd should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 37):

Simply, this should do the task:

```
import pandas as pd

grouped_df = df1.groupby( [ "Name", "City"] )

pd.DataFrame(grouped_df.size().reset_index(name = "Group_Count"))
```

Here, `grouped_df.size()` pulls up the unique groupby count, and `reset_index()` method resets the name of the column you want it to be.
Finally, the pandas `Dataframe()` function is called upon to create a DataFrame object.

Comment: Check out the .to_frame() method: grouped_df.size().to_frame('Group_Count')

Comment: reset_index doesn't have a name argument.

Comment: I was struck by the `name` argument too. Turns out the key is that `DataFrameGroupBy.size()` and friends return a *Series* by default, not a *DataFrame*. The `reset_index()` method on a `Series` **does** have `name`. The default return type can be changed by the `as_index` argument to `groupby()`. This loose typing and indirect method calling makes the document very hard to browse!

Answer (score 15):

Maybe I misunderstand the question but if you want to convert the groupby back to a dataframe you can use .to_frame(). I wanted to reset the index when I did this so I included that part as well.

example code unrelated to question

```
df = df['TIME'].groupby(df['Name']).min()
df = df.to_frame()
df = df.reset_index(level=['Name',"TIME"])
```

Answer (score 8):

I found this worked for me.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({ 
    "Name" : ["Alice", "Bob", "Mallory", "Mallory", "Bob" , "Mallory"] , 
    "City" : ["Seattle", "Seattle", "Portland", "Seattle", "Seattle", "Portland"]})

df1['City_count'] = 1
df1['Name_count'] = 1

df1.groupby(['Name', 'City'], as_index=False).count()
```

Answer (score 7):

Below solution may be simpler:

```
df1.reset_index().groupby( [ "Name", "City"],as_index=False ).count()
```

Answer (score 7):

This returns the ordinal levels/indices in the same order as a vanilla `groupby()` method. It's basically the same as the answer @NehalJWani posted in his comment, but stored in a variable with the `reset_index()` method called on it.

```
fare_class = df.groupby(['Satisfaction Rating','Fare Class']).size().to_frame(name = 'Count')
fare_class.reset_index()
```

This version not only returns the same data with percentages which is useful for stats, but also includes a lambda function.

```
fare_class_percent = df.groupby(['Satisfaction Rating', 'Fare Class']).size().to_frame(name = 'Percentage')
fare_class_percent.transform(lambda x: 100 * x/x.sum()).reset_index()

      Satisfaction Rating      Fare Class  Percentage
0            Dissatisfied        Business   14.624269
1            Dissatisfied         Economy   36.469048
2               Satisfied        Business    5.460425
3               Satisfied         Economy   33.235294
```

Example:
[image]

Answer (score 5):

I have aggregated with Qty wise data and store to dataframe

```
almo_grp_data = pd.DataFrame({'Qty_cnt' :
almo_slt_models_data.groupby( ['orderDate','Item','State Abv']
          )['Qty'].sum()}).reset_index()
```

Answer (score 4):

These solutions only partially worked for me because I was doing multiple aggregations. Here is a sample output of my grouped by that I wanted to convert to a dataframe:

[image: Groupby Output]

Because I wanted more than the count provided by reset_index(), I wrote a manual method for converting the image above into a dataframe. I understand this is not the most pythonic/pandas way of doing this as it is quite verbose and explicit, but it was all I needed. Basically, use the reset_index() method explained above to start a "scaffolding" dataframe, then loop through the group pairings in the grouped dataframe, retrieve the indices, perform your calculations against the ungrouped dataframe, and set the value in your new aggregated dataframe.

```
df_grouped = df[['Salary Basis', 'Job Title', 'Hourly Rate', 'Male Count', 'Female Count']]
df_grouped = df_grouped.groupby(['Salary Basis', 'Job Title'], as_index=False)

# Grouped gives us the indices we want for each grouping
# We cannot convert a groupedby object back to a dataframe, so we need to do it manually
# Create a new dataframe to work against
df_aggregated = df_grouped.size().to_frame('Total Count').reset_index()
df_aggregated['Male Count'] = 0
df_aggregated['Female Count'] = 0
df_aggregated['Job Rate'] = 0

def manualAggregations(indices_array):
    temp_df = df.iloc[indices_array]
    return {
        'Male Count': temp_df['Male Count'].sum(),
        'Female Count': temp_df['Female Count'].sum(),
        'Job Rate': temp_df['Hourly Rate'].max()
    }

for name, group in df_grouped:
    ix = df_grouped.indices[name]
    calcDict = manualAggregations(ix)

    for key in calcDict:
        #Salary Basis, Job Title
        columns = list(name)
        df_aggregated.loc[(df_aggregated['Salary Basis'] == columns[0]) & 
                          (df_aggregated['Job Title'] == columns[1]), key] = calcDict[key]
```

If a dictionary isn't your thing, the calculations could be applied inline in the for loop:

```
    df_aggregated['Male Count'].loc[(df_aggregated['Salary Basis'] == columns[0]) & 
                                (df_aggregated['Job Title'] == columns[1])] = df['Male Count'].iloc[ix].sum()
```

Comment: Could you please share the dataset you used for your solution? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

```
 grouped=df.groupby(['Team','Year'])['W'].count().reset_index()

 team_wins_df=pd.DataFrame(grouped)
 team_wins_df=team_wins_df.rename({'W':'Wins'},axis=1)
 team_wins_df['Wins']=team_wins_df['Wins'].astype(np.int32)
 team_wins_df.reset_index()
 print(team_wins_df)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set **group_keys=False** in the **group_by** method to prevent adding the group key to the index.

Example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({ 
    "Name" : ["Alice", "Bob", "Mallory", "Mallory", "Bob" , "Mallory"] , 
    "City" : ["Seattle", "Seattle", "Portland", "Seattle", "Seattle", "Portland"]})
df1.groupby(["Name"], group_keys=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

#### `.reset_index()` method / `as_index=False` parameter

In most practical cases, these two variations behave the same. In fact if we look at the [source code of groupby](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/0cdb37c445fc0a0a2144f981fd1acbf4f07d88ee/pandas/core/groupby/generic.py), for some methods, `as_index=False` is literally equivalent to `reset_index()`.

```py
# sample data
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': ['g1', 'g1', 'g2', 'g2'], 
    'B': [1, 1, 2, 2],
    'C': [1, 2, 3, 4]
})

y1 = df.groupby(['A', 'B'], as_index=False)['C'].sum()
y2 = df.groupby(['A', 'B'])['C'].sum().reset_index()
y1.equals(y2)   # True
```

Ultimately, `reset_index()` makes the following transformation (and passing `as_index=False` avoids the Series on the left altogether). Note that it creates a 3-column (number of grouper columns + column being aggregated) dataframe.

[image: result1]

`reset_index` and `as_index=False` behave differently, if a column used in the grouper is also in the output (as in the OP). In that case, `as_index=False` drops all overlapping columns from the grouper (via the [_insert_inaxis_grouper](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/0cdb37c445fc0a0a2144f981fd1acbf4f07d88ee/pandas/core/groupby/groupby.py#L1520-L1549) method). The following example illustrates this point.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['g1', 'g1', 'g2', 'g2'], 'B': [1, 1, 2, 2]})

df.groupby(['A', 'B'])['B'].sum()                           # <--- includes B as a grouper
df.groupby(['A', 'B'])['B'].sum().reset_index(name='Total') # <--- includes B as a grouper
df.groupby(['A', 'B'], as_index=False)['B'].sum()           # <--- drops B from the grouper
```

[image: differing case]

#### `.to_frame()` method / `groupby.method` on a list of columns

`to_frame()` method converts a Series into a DataFrame where the grouper is retained as the index and the values in the Series are converted into a DataFrame column. You can optionally pass a name for the aggregated column. However, if name is not passed, it's exactly the same as simply calling an aggregator function on a list of columns of groupby.

```py
x1 = df.groupby(['A', 'B'])['C'].sum().to_frame()
x2 = df.groupby(['A', 'B'])[['C']].sum()
#                          ^^   ^^  <--- list of columns
x1.equals(x2)   # True


# if `name=` is passed, it can rename the aggregated column in one go
x3 = df.groupby(['A', 'B'])['C'].sum().to_frame('Total')
x4 = df.groupby(['A', 'B'])[['C']].sum().rename(columns={'C': 'Total'})
x3.equals(x4)   # True
```

Ultimately, `to_frame(name)` makes the following transformation (and passing a list of columns to aggregate avoids the Series on the left altogether). Notice that unlike `reset_index()`, it creates a single column dataframe.

[image: result2]

---

Lastly, at least as of pandas 0.16.2, `groupby.count` method (the specific `groupby` method in the OP) returns an empty dataframe. However, calling count on each split via `groupby.agg` recovers the aggregated counts. As mentioned in jezrael's answer, listing all aggregated columns also works but if there are many columns, this case may be more readable.

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame({ 
    "Name": ["Alice", "Bob", "Mallory", "Mallory", "Bob" , "Mallory"], 
    "City": ["Seattle", "Seattle", "Portland", "Seattle", "Seattle", "Portland"]
})

df1.groupby(['Name', 'City']).count()                   # empty dataframe
df1.groupby(['Name', 'City']).agg(lambda x: x.count())  # OK
```

[image: result3]