# reading a csv and grouping data by a column

Tags: python, csv

I am working with a csv file with 3 columns that looks like this:

```
timeStamp, value, label
15:22:57, 849, CPU pid=26298:percent
15:22:57, 461000, JMX MB
15:22:58, 28683, Disks I/O
15:22:58, 3369078, Memory pid=26298:unit=mb:resident
15:22:58, 0, JMX 31690:gc-time
15:22:58, 0, CPU pid=26298:percent
15:22:58, 503000, JMX MB
```

The `label` column contains distinct values (say a total of 5), which include spaces, colons and other special characters.

What I am trying to achieve is to plot time against each metric (either on the same plot or on separate ones). I can do this with `matplotlib`, but I first need to group the `[timeStamps, value]` pairs according to the 'label'.

I looked into the `csv.DictReader` to get the labels and the `itertools.groupby` to group by the 'label', but I am struggling to do this in a proper 'pythonic' way.

Any suggestion?

Comment: What's your expected output for your example?

Comment: Well, given that my input samples are all mixed, I will probably have to separate the [times] and [values] for each [label]. My initial approach was to read the labels, then read each line and store each [time,value] pair based on the label. But this seems like a very inefficient way, which is why I wanted to look into dictionaries and iterators.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need `groupby`; you want to use [`collections.defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to collect series of `[timestamp, value]` pairs keyed by label:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import csv

per_label = defaultdict(list)

with open(inputfilename, 'rb') as inputfile:
    reader = csv.reader(inputfile)
    next(reader, None)  # skip the header row

    for timestamp, value, label in reader:
        per_label[label.strip()].append([timestamp.strip(), float(value)])
```

Now `per_label` is a dictionary with labels as keys, and a list of `[timestamp, value]` pairs as values; I've stripped off whitespace (your input sample has a lot of extra whitespace) and turned the `value` column into floats.

For your (limited) input sample that results in:

```
{'CPU pid=26298:percent': [['15:22:57', 849.0], ['15:22:58', 0.0]],
 'Disks I/O': [['15:22:58', 28683.0]],
 'JMX 31690:gc-time': [['15:22:58', 0.0]],
 'JMX MB': [['15:22:57', 461000.0], ['15:22:58', 503000.0]],
 'Memory pid=26298:unit=mb:resident': [['15:22:58', 3369078.0]]}
```

Comment: This worked like a charm! Thanks
My file may end up having more than 3 columns, but I think I can handle this. I am assuming I just need to add:
    for timestamp, value, label, <extra columns> in reader:

Comment: @ArgyriosTzakas: You can also just do `for row in reader`, then use indices, `row[1]`, `row[5]`, etc. `csv.DictReader()` would replace the list with a dict so you can do `row['timeStamp']` instead of `row[0]`; leave out the `next()` call if you switch to `reader.DictReader`.

Comment: Thanks Martijn. On a related topic, is there a clever way of splitting my dictionary based on the keys, without having to hard-code? For example, I can do this
l1, l2, l3 = per_label.values()
but what if I have more than 3 keys?

Comment: @ArgyriosTzakas: Why do you need to unpack the values? By unpacking to 3 variables you are already hardcoding variable names. Just loop over the dictionary: `for key in per_label:` or `for value in per_label.values():`, etc., or store all values in a list: `values_list = per_label.values()` then loop over that somewhere else.

Answer (score 5):

You can try [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) which provide a nice structure to dealing with data.

Read the csv to the `DataFrame`

```
In [123]: import pandas as pd

In [124]: df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', skipinitialspace=True)

In [125]: df
Out[125]: 
  timeStamp    value                              label
0  15:22:57      849              CPU pid=26298:percent
1  15:22:57   461000                             JMX MB
2  15:22:58    28683                          Disks I/O 
3  15:22:58  3369078  Memory pid=26298:unit=mb:resident
4  15:22:58        0                  JMX 31690:gc-time
5  15:22:58        0              CPU pid=26298:percent
6  15:22:58   503000                             JMX MB
```

Group the `DataFrame` by `label`

```
In [154]: g =  df.groupby('label')
```

Now you can get what you want

```
In [155]: g.get_group('JMX MB')
Out[155]:
  timeStamp   value   label
1  15:22:57  461000  JMX MB
6  15:22:58  503000  JMX MB
```

Comment: Very interesting. I will have a look into Pandas as I will be doing many similar data manipulations. Thanks!

Comment: Can you add how to write the grouped CSV to file? Not quite trivial: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10373660/1333493

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`numpy.loadtxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html):

```
import numpy as np
result = np.loadtxt('MYFILE', usecols=(0, 1, 2), 
          dtype=[('time', 'S8'), ('values', np.uint), ('label', 'S33')], 
          delimiter=', ')
```

This will load your table into a structured array, where time is saved as a string of 8 characters ('S8'), values as unsigned integer and the label as a string with max 33 characters ('S33',  you may have to adjust this size). Then you can index you values by the type:

```
>>> print result['values']
[    849  461000   28683 3369078       0       0  503000]
```

And filter according to label, if you want:

```
>>> print result['values'][result['label'] == 'JMX MB']
[461000 503000]
```

To convert the times from strings to floats, you can use `pylab`'s date `datestr2num` and supply it as a converter to `loadtxt`:

```
import pylab
result = np.loadtxt('MYFILE', usecols=(0, 1, 2), 
           dtype=[('time', np.float), ('values', np.uint), ('label', 'S33')],
           delimiter=', ', converters={0: pylab.datestr2num})
```