# separating groups in csv - using tkinter to display results

Tags: python, csv, tkinter

I have a csv file with a name the first column and either A or B in the second. 
I want to analyse this (what group their in) and put there names into the corresponding text box in tkinter, how would i go about this?

```
from tkinter import *
import csv

master=Tk()

file=open(file="Book1.csv")
f=csv.reader(file)
people=[]
for column in f:
    people.append(column[0:2])


classAl=Label(master,text='A',width=10).grid(row=1,column=1)
classA=Text(master,width=10)
classA.grid(column=1,row=2)

classbl=Label(master,text='B',width=10).grid(row=1,column=2)
classB=Text(master,width=10)
classB.grid(column=2,row=2)

print(people)

grouplist=[x[1] for x in people]
for names in(grouplist):
    print(names)
```

this is the coding i have so far, i can read what group they are in but i'm not sure on how to then put its corresponding name into the correct place.
any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a collections.defaultdict to group the contents of your csv file by label (see [this other stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16210941/python-reading-a-csv-and-grouping-data-by-a-column))

A Listbox would be more appropriate widget for your application.

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict
from tkinter import *

grouped = defaultdict(list)

# Open the csv file and use the defaultdict to group by label.
with open('Book1.csv', 'r') as fh:
    book = csv.reader(fh)
    for name, label in book:
        grouped[label].append(name)

master = Tk()
A_label = Label(master, text='A', width=10).grid(row=1, column=1)
A_list = Listbox(master, width=10)
A_list.grid(column=1, row=2)
for name in grouped['A']:
    A_list.insert(END, name)

B_label = Label(master, text='B', width=10).grid(row=1, column=2)
B_list = Listbox(master, width=10)
B_list.grid(column=2, row=2)
for name in grouped['B']:
    B_list.insert(END, name)

master.mainloop()
```

It is better to open and read the csv file using the with statement (context manager).

I applied some general [pep8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) recommendations to the code as well.