# How to assign a name to the size() column?

Tags: python, pandas

I am using `.size()` on a groupby result in order to count how many items are in each group.

I would like the result to be saved to a new column name without manually editing the column names array, how can it be done?

This is what I have tried:

```
grpd = df.groupby(['A','B'])
grpd['size'] = grpd.size()
grpd
```

and the error I got:

> TypeError: 'DataFrameGroupBy' object does not support item assignment
> (on the second line)

Comment: worth noting that ``size`` is a bad choice for a column, since it's a builtin method on every object under pandas, so you can only retrive it through ``getitem`` and not through ``getattr``.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The result of `df.groupby(...)` is not a DataFrame. To get a DataFrame back, you have to apply a function to each group, transform each element of a group, or filter the groups.

It seems like you want a DataFrame that contains (1) all your original data in `df` and (2) the count of how much data is in each group. These things have different lengths, so if they need to go into the same DataFrame, you'll need to list the size redundantly, i.e., for each row in each group.

```
df['size'] = df.groupby(['A','B']).transform(np.size)
```

(Aside: It's helpful if you can show succinct sample input and expected results.)

Comment: I also found this which is almost equal (creates a new dataframe), but not sure how it compares with your solution in terms of efficiency http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10373660/converting-a-pandas-groupby-object-to-dataframe

Comment: More over your solution works well on a toy example, but on the actual data an error is returned http://pastebin.com/aCsMxCd5

Comment: In pandas 20.3, @jezraels's `df['size'] = df.groupby(['A','B']) .A .transform(np.size)` works; without the `.A` you get "ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 1", i.e. "got 2 columns, need 1" .

Answer (score 122):

The `.size()` built-in method of DataFrameGroupBy objects actually returns a Series object with the group sizes and not a DataFrame. If you want a DataFrame whose column is the group sizes, indexed by the groups, with a custom name, you can use the `.to_frame()` method and use the desired column name as its argument.

```
grpd = df.groupby(['A','B']).size().to_frame('size')
```

If you wanted the groups to be columns again you could add a `.reset_index()` at the end.

Answer (score 55):

You need [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) - `len` of `df` is same as before:

Notice:

*Here it is necessary to add one column after `groupby`, else you get an error. Because [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) count `NaN`s too, what column is used is not important. All columns working same.*

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['x', 'x', 'x','y','y']
                , 'B': ['a', 'c', 'c','b','b']})
print (df)
   A  B
0  x  a
1  x  c
2  x  c
3  y  b
4  y  b

df['size'] = df.groupby(['A', 'B'])['A'].transform('size')
print (df)
   A  B  size
0  x  a     1
1  x  c     2
2  x  c     2
3  y  b     2
4  y  b     2
```

If need set column name in aggregating `df` - `len` of `df` is obviously **NOT** same as before:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['x', 'x', 'x','y','y']
                , 'B': ['a', 'c', 'c','b','b']})
print (df)
   A  B
0  x  a
1  x  c
2  x  c
3  y  b
4  y  b

df = df.groupby(['A', 'B']).size().reset_index(name='Size')
print (df)
   A  B  Size
0  x  a     1
1  x  c     2
2  y  b     2
```

Comment: Nice one. But how do I do the same as this `df.groupby(['A', 'B']).size().reset_index(name='Size')` If I have multiple index?

Comment: @Sotos If use last version of pandas, same way.

Comment: so something like `...reset_index('V1', name = 'size')`?

Comment: @Sotos Hmmm, it does not work this way. Need `.reset_index().rename(columns='index':'col', 'anothercol':'col2')`

Comment: That is exactly what I did at the end... `(full_df
          .set_index('cdatetime')
          .groupby(['Cluster', 'source', 'action', pd.Grouper(freq = 'H', sort = True)])
          .size()
          .reset_index(['Cluster', 'source', 'action'])
          .rename(columns={0: 'cnt'})
          )`

Comment: Awesome answer. Could you explain again why I will get an error just because GroupBy.size count NaNs too? A Type Error is raised even though there is no NaNs in the dataframe. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

You can set the `as_index` parameter in `groupby` to `False` to get a DataFrame instead of a Series:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b'], 'B': [1, 2, 2, 2]})

df.groupby(['A', 'B'], as_index=False).size()
```

Output:

```
   A  B  size
0  a  1     1
1  a  2     1
2  b  2     2
```

Answer (score 0):

lets say n is the name of dataframe and cst is the no of items being repeted. 
Below code gives the count in next column

```
cstn=Counter(n.cst)
cstlist = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(cstn, orient='index').reset_index()
cstlist.columns=['name','cnt']
n['cnt']=n['cst'].map(cstlist.loc[:, ['name','cnt']].set_index('name').iloc[:,0].to_dict())
```

Hope this will work