# group by in Pandas DataFrame Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm new to Pandas and I'd like to know what I'm doing wrong in the following example.

I found an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17995024/how-to-assign-a-name-to-the-a-size-column?lq=1) explaining how to get a data frame after applying a group by instead of a series.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame( { 
"Name" : ["Alice", "Bob", "Mallory", "Mallory", "Bob" , "Mallory"] , 
"City" : ["Seattle", "Seattle", "Baires", "Caracas", "Baires", "Caracas"] })

df1['size'] = df1.groupby(['City']).transform(np.size)

df1.dtypes #Why is size an object? shouldn't it be an integer?

df1[['size']] = df1[['size']].astype(int) #convert to integer

df1['avera'] = df1.groupby(['City'])['size'].transform(np.mean) #group by again
```

Basically, I want to apply the same transformation to a huge data set I'm working on now, but I'm getting an error message:

```
budgetbid['meanpb']=budgetbid.groupby(['jobid'])['probudget'].transform(np.mean) #can't upload this data for the sake of explanation

ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 5564 elements, new values have 78421 elements
```

Thus, my questions are:

1. How can I overcome this error?
2. Why do I get an object type when apply group by with size instead of an integer type?
3. Let us say that I want to get a data frame from `df1` with unique cities and their respective `count(*)`. I know I can do something like

   newdf=df1.groupby(['City']).size()

Unfortunately, this is a series, but I want a data frame with two columns, `City` and the brand new variable, let's say `countcity`. How can I get a data frame from a group-by operation like the one in this example?

4. Could you give me an example of a `select distinct` equivalence here in pandas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Question 2: *Why does `df1['size']` have dtype `object`?*

`groupby/transform` returns a DataFrame with a [dtype for each column which is compatible](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/groupby.py#L2463) with both the original column's dtype and the result of the transformation. Since `Name` has dtype object,

```
df1.groupby(['City']).transform(np.size)
```

is converted to dtype object as well.

I'm not sure why `transform` is coded to work like this; there might be some usecase which demands this to ensure correctness in some sense.

---

Questions 1 & 3: *Why do I get `ValueError: Length mismatch` and how can I avoid it*

There are probably NaNs in the column being grouped. For example, suppose we change one of the values in `City` to `NaN`:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame( { 
    "Name" : ["Alice", "Bob", "Mallory", "Mallory", "Bob" , "Mallory"] , 
    "City" : [np.nan, "Seattle", "Baires", "Caracas", "Baires", "Caracas"] })
grouped = df2.groupby(['City'])
```

then

```
In [86]: df2.groupby(['City']).transform(np.size)
ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 5 elements, new values have 6 elements
```

Groupby does not group the NaNs:

```
In [88]: [city for city, grp in  df2.groupby(['City'])]
Out[88]: ['Baires', 'Caracas', 'Seattle']
```

To work around this, use `groupby/agg`:

```
countcity = grouped.agg('count').rename(columns={'Name':'countcity'})
#          countcity
# City              
# Baires           2
# Caracas          2
# Seattle          1
```

and then merge the result back into `df2`:

```
result = pd.merge(df2, countcity, left_on=['City'], right_index=True, how='outer')
print(result)
```

yields

```
      City     Name  countcity
0      NaN    Alice        NaN
1  Seattle      Bob          1
2   Baires  Mallory          2
4   Baires      Bob          2
3  Caracas  Mallory          2
5  Caracas  Mallory          2
```

---

Question 4: Do you mean *what is the Pandas equivalent of the SQL `select distinct` statement?*

If so, perhaps you are looking for
[Series.unique](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unique.html)
or perhaps iterate through the keys in the Groupby object, as was done in

```
[city for city, grp in df2.groupby(['City'])]
```

Answer (score 1):

3.)

Just call `pd.Dataframe()` again:

`newdf = pd.Dataframe(df1.City.value_counts())`

or

`newdf = pd.Dataframe(groupby(['City']).size())`

4.) I think the `select distinct` euqivalent would just be using more than one column in your groupby.  So for example,

`df1.groupby(['City', 'Name']).size()` would return the groupby object:

```
City     Name   
Baires   Bob        1
         Mallory    1
Caracas  Mallory    2
Seattle  Alice      1
         Bob        1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: For 3, I would complement it by adding `newdf=newdf.reset_index('City')` and then `newdf.columns=['City','countcity']`