# Set column name for size()

Tags: pandas

I'm trying to rename the `size()` column as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17995024/how-to-assign-a-name-to-the-a-size-column) like this:

```
x = monthly.copy()

x["size"] = x\
      .groupby(["sub_acct_id", "clndr_yr_month"]).transform(np.size)
```

But what I'm getting is

```
ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 15, placement implies 1
```

Why is this not working for my dataframe?

---

If I simple print the copy:

```
x = monthly.copy()
print x
```

this is how the table looks like:

```
sub_acct_id  clndr_yr_month
12716D       201601             219
             201602             265
12716G       201601             221
             201602             262
12716K       201601             181
             201602             149
...
```

what I try to accomplish is to set the name of the column:

```
sub_acct_id  clndr_yr_month     size
12716D       201601             219
             201602             265
12716G       201601             221
             201602             262
12716K       201601             181
             201602             149
...
```

Comment: What about `x["size"] = x.groupby(["sub_acct_id", "clndr_yr_month"]).transform(len)` ?

Comment: @jezrael Nope, giving me the same error :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need:

```
x["size"] = x.groupby(["sub_acct_id", "clndr_yr_month"])['sub_acct_id'].transform('size')
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'sub_acct_id': ['x', 'x', 'x','x','y','y','y','z','z']
                , 'clndr_yr_month': ['a', 'b', 'c','c','a','b','c','a','b']})
print (df)
  clndr_yr_month sub_acct_id
0              a           x
1              b           x
2              c           x
3              c           x
4              a           y
5              b           y
6              c           y
7              a           z
8              b           z

df['size'] = df.groupby(['sub_acct_id', 'clndr_yr_month'])['sub_acct_id'].transform('size')
print (df)
  clndr_yr_month sub_acct_id  size
0              a           x     1
1              b           x     1
2              c           x     2
3              c           x     2
4              a           y     1
5              b           y     1
6              c           y     1
7              a           z     1
8              b           z     1
```

---

Another solution with aggregating output:

```
df = df.groupby(['sub_acct_id', 'clndr_yr_month']).size().reset_index(name='Size')
print (df)
  sub_acct_id clndr_yr_month  Size
0           x              a     1
1           x              b     1
2           x              c     2
3           y              a     1
4           y              b     1
5           y              c     1
6           z              a     1
7           z              b     1
```