# Reshape Pandas DatafRames by binary columns value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, reshape

Can't figure out how to reshape my DataFrame into new one by several binary columns value.

Input:

```
data         code    a  b   c

2016-01-07   foo     0  0   0
2016-01-12   bar     0  0   1
2016-01-03   gar     0  1   0
2016-01-22   foo     1  1   0
2016-01-26   bar     1  1   0
```

I want to reshape by binary values, i.e. column **a/b/c**, if their value  == 1, I need every time new column
with all data.

Expected output:

```
         data       code        
  a   2016-01-22    foo      
  a   2016-01-26    bar       
  b   2016-01-03    gar     
  b   2016-01-22    foo      
  b   2016-01-26    bar       
  c   2016-01-12    bar
```

Stucked here from the morning, will appreciate help very much !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) with filtering `1` in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing), [`DataFrame.pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) is used for removing column after filtration:

```
df = df.melt(['data','code'], var_name='type')
df = df[df.pop('value').eq(1)]
print (df)
          data code type
3   2016-01-22  foo    a
4   2016-01-26  bar    a
7   2016-01-03  gar    b
8   2016-01-22  foo    b
9   2016-01-26  bar    b
11  2016-01-12  bar    c
```

Comment: Save my time !
How can I also add additional column with number of each type appears ? (for all a - 2, b - 3, c - 1)?

Comment: @unkind58 - sure, you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17995024)

Comment: @unkind58 - it means `df['size'] = df.groupby(['type'])['type'].transform('size')`

Comment: `df['number'] = df['type'].map(dict(a=1,b=2,c=3))`

Comment: @jezreal what transform size do?

Comment: @adirabargil - It repeat counts for new column