# How to get unique values from multiple columns in a pandas groupby

Tags: python, pandas

Starting from this dataframe df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'c':[1,1,1,2,2,2],'l1':['a','a','b','c','c','b'],'l2':['b','d','d','f','e','f']})

   c l1 l2
0  1  a  b
1  1  a  d
2  1  b  d
3  2  c  f
4  2  c  e
5  2  b  f
```

I would like to perform a groupby over the `c` column to get unique values of the `l1` and `l2` columns. For one columns I can do:

```
g = df.groupby('c')['l1'].unique()
```

that correctly returns:

```
c
1    [a, b]
2    [c, b]
Name: l1, dtype: object
```

but using:

```
g = df.groupby('c')['l1','l2'].unique()
```

returns:

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'unique'
```

I know I can get the unique values for the two columns with (among others):

```
In [12]: np.unique(df[['l1','l2']])
Out[12]: array(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'], dtype=object)
```

Is there a way to apply this method to the groupby in order to get something like:

```
c
1    [a, b, d]
2    [c, b, e, f]
Name: l1, dtype: object
```

Comment: is there a way you can have the output as distinct columns instead of one cell having a list?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You can do it with `apply`:

```
import numpy as np
g = df.groupby('c')['l1','l2'].apply(lambda x: list(np.unique(x)))
```

Answer (score 63):

Alternatively, you can use `agg`:

```
g = df.groupby('c')['l1','l2'].agg(['unique'])
```

Comment: how would you combine 'unique' and let's say '.join' in the same agg?

Comment: You can write a custom function and apply it the same way. For example: `f = lambda arr: ','.join(np.unique(arr))` --> then `.agg([f])` or, if you want to label it: `.agg([('MyName', f)])`

Comment: @YaakovBressler how do you actually get the resulting values in order?

Comment: You could sort the data at any point! Best performance would be to sort after the aggregation -> `df.groupby(...).agg()..sort_values()` More context + options here: [**pandas groupby, then sort within groups**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27842613/pandas-groupby-then-sort-within-groups) @josepmaria

Comment: Visiting this in 2023, this is the correct answer. While you CAN use apply, this approach with agg is much more readable and flexible.

Answer (score 15):

One more alternative is to use [`GroupBy.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) with [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-set)

```
df.groupby('c').agg(set)

       l1      l2
c                
1  {a, b}  {d, b}
2  {c, b}  {e, f}
```

Comment: You might get into trouble with this when the values in l1 and l2 aren't hashable (ex timestamps). Otherwise, solid solution.

Comment: Beautiful solution but it doesn't work for nan.

Answer (score 0):

A shorter version without the lambda function:

```
df.groupby('c').apply(np.unique)
# or df.groupby('c')['l1','l2'].apply(np.unique)
```

Output:

```
c
1       [a, b, d]
2    [b, c, e, f]
dtype: object
```