# Get a list of values from a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a DataFrame like this

```
df.head()
>>>
Date Region   Manager   SalesMan    Item         Units  Unit_price  Sale_amt
 0   East     Martha    Alexander   Television   ...      ...         ...
 1   Central  Hermann   Shelli      Home Theater ...      ...         ...
 2   Central  Hermann   Luis        Television   ...      ...         ...
 3   Central  Timothy   David       CellPhone    ...      ...         ...
 4   West     Timothy   Stephen     Television   ...      ...         ...
```

Here are the unique Managers and SalesMen

```
df['Manager'].unique()
array(['Martha', 'Hermann', 'Timothy', 'Douglas'], dtype=object)


df['SalesMan'].unique()
array(['Alexander', 'Shelli', 'Luis', 'David', 'Stephen', 'Steven',
       'Michael', 'Sigal', 'Diana', 'Karen', 'John'], dtype=object)
```

I want a dataframe that contains Unique Managers and the list of unique Salesmen under those managers
For example, for the above dataframe, I want an output like:

```
Manager     list_of_salesmen
Martha      [ALexander]
Herman      [Shelli, Luis]
Timothy     [David, Stephen]
```

I thought of using groupby and got struck in there!
How do I go about solving this problem?

Comment: This could help https://stackoverflow.com/a/59887985/14066512

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get unique values from multiple columns in a pandas groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36106490/how-to-get-unique-values-from-multiple-columns-in-a-pandas-groupby)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `groupby.agg` on Manager, and pass `list` to SalesMan:

```
>>> df.groupby('Manager').agg({'SalesMan':list})

                SalesMan
Manager                  
Hermann    [Shelli, Luis]
Martha        [Alexander]
Timothy  [David, Stephen]
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by making a `dict()` object that contains data for new dataset and use `pandas.DataFrame.from_dict()` to convert it to dataframe:

```
d = {'Manager':list(df['Manager'].unique()), 'SalesMan':[]}

for i in df['Manager'].unique():
    d['SalesMan'].append([i for i in df[df['Manager'] == i]['SalesMan']])

df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d)
```