# How to show values in pandas pie chart?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, pie-chart

I would like to visualize the amount of laps a certain go-kart has driven within a pie chart. To achive this i would like to count the amount of laptime groupedby kartnumber. I found there are two ways to create such a pie chart:

**1#**

```
df.groupby('KartNumber')['Laptime'].count().plot.pie()
```

**2#**

```
df.groupby(['KartNumber']).count().plot(kind='pie', y='Laptime')
```

**print(df)**

```
print(df)
     HeatNumber  NumberOfKarts KartNumber DriverName  Laptime
0           334             11          5    Monique   53.862
1           334             11          5    Monique   59.070
2           334             11          5    Monique   47.832
3           334             11          5    Monique   47.213
4           334             11          5    Monique   51.975
...         ...            ...        ...        ...      ...
4053        437              2         20       luuk   39.678
4054        437              2         20       luuk   39.872
4055        437              2         20       luuk   39.454
4056        437              2         20       luuk   39.575
4057        437              2         20       luuk   39.648
```

**Output not with plot:**

```
KartNumber
1       203
10      277
11      133
12      244
13      194
14      172
15      203
16      134
17      253
18      247
19      240
2       218
20      288
21       14
4       190
5       314
6        54
60       55
61        9
62       70
63       65
64       29
65       53
66       76
67       42
68       28
69       32
8        49
9       159
None     13
```

As you can see i have the kartnumbers and count of laptimes. But i would like to show the count of laptimes within the pie chart(or legend). I tried using autopct but couldnt get it working properly. Does anyone knows how to achive my desired situation?

Edit: For more information on this dataset please see: [How to get distinct rows from pandas dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72337522/how-to-get-distinct-rows-from-pandas-dataframe?noredirect=1#comment127795529_72337522)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Complete awswer:

```
    autopct=lambda x: '{:.0f}'.format(x * (df['Laptime'].count()) / 100))
```

Answer (score 5):

@Mathijs and @Danielgard

Well, actually, you can, look at my example below:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(32, 8), subplot_kw=dict(aspect="equal"))

recipe = ["1 cl. Vanilla Concentrate ",
          "8 cl. Orange Juice",
          "8 cl. Pineapple Juice",
          "4 cl. orgeat Syrup"]

data = [float(x.split()[0]) for x in recipe]
ingredients = [' '.join(x.split()[-2:]) for x in recipe]


def func(pct, allvals):
    absolute = int(pct/100.*np.sum(allvals))
    return "{:.1f}%\n({:d} cl.)".format(pct, absolute)


wedges, texts, autotexts = ax.pie(data, autopct=lambda pct: func(pct, data),
                                  textprops=dict(color="w"))

ax.legend(wedges, ingredients,
          title="Ingredients",
          loc="center left",
          bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0, 0.5, 1))

plt.setp(autotexts, size=10, weight="bold")

ax.set_title("TIE-BREAK ALCOOL FREE COCKTAIL RECIPE")

plt.show()
```

**Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 4):

By using a command like:

```
plt.pie(values, labels=labels, autopct='%.2f')
```

By setting up autopct at this format, it will show you the percentage in each part of the graph. If there is any problem, please share a screenshot of your result .

Comment: Yes i know how to add a percentage,  but i would like to add the value of the count if that is possible. Thanks you for the fast response! :)

Comment: As much as I know it impossible because the point of that specific chart is to show you information relatively, hope I right.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented like below,
df_company is the input data frame, and we can control the format with `autopct=fmt`. value and % display control from  `'{:.1f}%\n{:.0f}'.format(x, total*x/100)` defined in fmt function.

```
total = df_company['type'].value_counts().values.sum()
def fmt(x):
    return '{:.1f}%\n{:.0f}'.format(x, total*x/100)


plt.figure(figsize=(15,15))
plt.pie(df_company['type'].value_counts().values,  autopct=fmt, textprops={'fontsize': 13})
```

[image]