# How can I compact info in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas data frame with 3 columns: id, start_time, channel.
for example:

| id | start_time | channel |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | b | c |
| a | b | d |
| a | f | g |
| e | h | i |

etc..

I would like to compact the table and have something like this:

| id | start_time | channel |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | [b,f] | [c,d,g] |
| e | h | i |

(The id has to be unique value). For every id can I have one or more start_time and channel.
I appreciate any help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get unique values from multiple columns in a pandas groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36106490/how-to-get-unique-values-from-multiple-columns-in-a-pandas-groupby)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `unique` after `groupby`:

```
df.groupby('id', as_index=False).agg(lambda x: x.unique())
```

Output:

```
   id   start_time  channel
0   a   [b, f]      [c, d, g]
1   e   [h]          [i]
```