# Pandas: sort within groupby on a particular column

Tags: pandas

The data set I'm working with is [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/justmarkham/DAT8/master/data/chipotle.tsv). It's a data set of Chipotle orders. There are `item_name` for each type of item sold, and then within `item_name` there are multiple possible `choice_description`s describing exactly what is in the item.

So let's import the file first and clean it up a bit:

```
chipo = pd.read_csv('chipotle.tsv', sep='\t')
del chipo['order_id']
del chipo['quantity']
chipo['revenue'] = chipo['item_price'].str.replace('$','').astype(float)
chipo['count'] = 1
```

I'm trying to tabulate how many of each `choice_description` is ordered per team `item_name`. This is easy enough by using a groupby and then summing the columns (including the column of ones),

```
grouped = chipo.groupby(['item_name','choice_description']).sum()
```

but now I want to **sort the counts within `'item_name'`.** Oh, also I want to keep the `item_price` column for possible later calculation, so I can't just convert the DataFrame to a one-column frame. For the life of me I can't figure out how to do this.

I can't just call `grouped.sort_values('count')` because it sorts over all observations, not just within the `item_name` groups. How can I just sort by that column but keep the sorting constrained within the group?

Even though there seem to previous answers discussing this (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27842613/pandas-groupby-sort-within-groups)), all of them either use deprecated sort commands (e.g. `Series.order()` or `DataFrame.sort()`) or don't do exactly what I need. How can I perform this seemingly simple task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I just sort by that column but keep the sorting constrained within the group?

Sort by both `item_name` and `count`. Since `item_name` is an index level, and `count` is a column, we must either move `item_name` to a column and call `DataFrame.sort_values` or move `count` into the index and call `DataFrame.sortlevel`.

For example

```
import pandas as pd
chipo = pd.read_csv('chipotle.tsv', sep='\t')
del chipo['order_id']
del chipo['quantity']
chipo['revenue'] = chipo['item_price'].str.replace('$','').astype(float)
chipo['count'] = 1
result = chipo.groupby(['item_name','choice_description']).sum()

result = (result.set_index('count', append=True)
            .sortlevel(axis=0, level=['item_name', 'count'], ascending=False)
            .reset_index('count', drop=False))
```

yields

```
                                                                          revenue  \
                                                                      revenue  count
item_name             choice_description                                                
Veggie Salad Bowl     [Fresh Tomato Salsa, [Fajita Vegetables, Lettuc...    11.25      1
                      [Fresh Tomato Salsa, [Fajita Vegetables, Rice, ...    11.25      1
                      [Fresh Tomato Salsa, [Fajita Vegetables, Rice, ...    11.25      1
                      [Fresh Tomato Salsa, [Rice, Lettuce, Guacamole,...    11.25      1
...                      
Barbacoa Bowl         [Roasted Chili Corn Salsa, [Fajita Vegetables, ...    23.50      2
                      [Fresh Tomato Salsa, [Fajita Vegetables, Rice, ...     9.25      1
                      [Fresh Tomato Salsa, [Fajita Vegetables, Rice, ...     9.25      1
                      [Tomatillo Red Chili Salsa, [Fajita Vegetables,...    11.75      1
                      [Tomatillo Red Chili Salsa, [Rice, Black Beans,...     9.25      1
                      [Tomatillo Red Chili Salsa, [Rice, Cheese, Lett...     9.25      1
                      [Tomatillo Red Chili Salsa, [Rice, Pinto Beans,...     9.25      1
                      [[Tomatillo-Green Chili Salsa (Medium), Roasted...    11.48      1
                      [[Tomatillo-Red Chili Salsa (Hot), Tomatillo-Gr...     8.99      1
6 Pack Soft Drink     [Diet Coke]                                           19.47      3
                      [Coke]                                                 6.49      1
                      [Sprite]                                               6.49      1

[314 rows x 2 columns]
```

---

Of the two options above, using `sortlevel` is a bit quicker than `sort_values`. 
Here is a benchmark:

```
In [73]: %timeit using_sortlevel(totals)
10 loops, best of 3: 148 ms per loop

In [74]: %timeit using_sort_values(totals)
10 loops, best of 3: 174 ms per loop
```

using this setup:

```
import pandas as pd
N = 10**6
chipo = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1000, size=(N,4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
totals = chipo.groupby(['A','B']).sum()

def using_sortlevel(df):
    return (df.set_index('C', append=True)
            .sortlevel(axis=0, level=['A', 'C'], ascending=False)
            .reset_index('C', drop=False))

def using_sort_values(df):
    return (df.reset_index('A')
            .sort_values(by=['A', 'C'], ascending=False)
            .set_index('A', append=True)
            .swaplevel(0, 1, axis=0))
```

Comment: Interesting. I would've thought that there would be a more "built-in" way to do this (not that this is difficult to do or anything). Thanks.