# How to group by one column and sort the values of another column?

Tags: python, sorting, pandas, group-by

Here is my dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['one', 'one', 'two', 'two', 'one'] ,
                   'B': ['Ar', 'Br', 'Cr', 'Ar','Ar'] ,
                   'C': ['12/15/2011', '11/11/2001', '08/30/2015', '07/3/1999','03/03/2000' ],
                      'D':[1,7,3,4,5]})
```

My goal is to group by column `A` and sort within grouped results by column `B`.

Here is what I came up with:

```
sort_group = df.sort_values('B').groupby('A')
```

I was hoping that grouping operation would not distort order, but it does not work and also returns not a dataframe, but `groupby` object

```
<pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy object at 0x0000000008B190B8>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pandas groupby sort within groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27842613/pandas-groupby-sort-within-groups)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You cannot apply `sort_values` directly to a `groupby` object but you need an `apply`:

```
df.groupby('A').apply(lambda x: x.sort_values('B'))
```

gives you the desired output:

```
         A   B           C  D
A                            
one 0  one  Ar  12/15/2011  1
    4  one  Ar  03/03/2000  5
    1  one  Br  11/11/2001  7
two 3  two  Ar   07/3/1999  4
    2  two  Cr  08/30/2015  3
```

Answer (score 1):

I usually use only `sort_values` to *indirectly* group values based on *column A* and sort within the groups by *column B*. This is:

```
sort_group = df.sort_values(['A', 'B'])
```

which will give you this:

```
    A   B          C    D
0   one Ar  12/15/2011  1
4   one Ar  03/03/2000  5
1   one Br  11/11/2001  7
3   two Ar  07/3/1999   4
2   two Cr  08/30/2015  3
```

This will return a normal DataFrame where you continue your analysis.