# Pandas groupby sort within groups retaining multiple aggregates

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, pandas-groupby

I want to apply a sort and a limit within the groups returned by `groupby`, as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27842613/pandas-groupby-sort-within-groups). However, I have multiple aggregates and I want all of the aggregates to be retained in the result.

Here is a simple example:

```
products = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
stores = ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
n = 30

product_list = [products[i] for i in np.random.randint(0, len(products), n)]
store_list = [stores[i] for i in np.random.randint(0, len(stores), n)]
rating_list = np.random.random(n) * 5
sales_list = np.random.random(n) * 10000

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'store': store_list, 
     'product': product_list, 
     'sales': sales_list, 
     'rating': rating_list})

df = df[['store', 'product', 'sales', 'rating']]

df[:5]
```

[image: ungrouped dataframe]

I want to group by `store` and `product`, and both `sum` and `count` the `sales`, while taking the `mean` of the `rating`.

This is straightforward:

```
dfg = df.groupby(['store', 'product']).agg({'sales': ['sum', 'count'], 
                                            'rating': 'mean'})
```

[image: grouped]

Now, I want to only keep the top two rated rows in each group. I can get this as follows (using a multi-level extension of the somewhat unintuitive [to me] incantations from [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27842613/pandas-groupby-sort-within-groups)):

```
g = dfg[('rating', 'mean')].groupby(
      level=0, group_keys=False).apply(
        lambda x: x.sort_values(ascending=False).head(2))
g
```

This returns the following `Series`:

```
store  product
bar    B          3.601135
       A          1.867449
baz    B          2.984196
       D          2.780500
foo    B          3.767912
       D          3.129346
Name: (rating, mean), dtype: float64
```

But I've lost the `('sales', 'sum')` and `('sales', 'count')` columns.

I suspect I need to extract `g.index` and use it in some way but have not been able to get this sorted (pun intended).

EDIT: The answers below manage to give the groups that I'm looking for, but what I'd really like is a stable sort where not only do I get the top N mean ratings within each group, but the groups themselves are sorted so that the first group has the highest rating, etc. To some extent this is just icing on the cake as I have the values I want now and would just like the report to be prettier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've sorted it. Instead of indexing the grouped table and doing the subsequent `groupby` and `sort_values` as above, I needed to apply the `sort_values` to the un-indexed `DataFrame`, specifying the column to sort on explicitly:

```
g = dfg.groupby(level=0, group_keys=False).apply(
      lambda x: x.sort_values(('rating', 'mean'), ascending=False).head(2))
```

Giving me the desired result:

[image]

Comment: Ah, sorry, didn't see you post your answer when I did. Shall I remove?

Answer (score 3):

This is how you'd do it, using `sort_values` + `groupby` + `head` -

```
dfg.sort_values(('rating', 'mean'), ascending=False)\
   .groupby(level=0)\
   .head(2)\
   .sort_index()

                 rating         sales      
                   mean           sum count
store product                              
bar   B        4.388521    636.813757     1
      C        3.931341   1843.772878     1
baz   A        2.501077  23110.162196     4
      B        3.339784  10610.257660     2
foo   B        2.785306  10315.968161     2
      D        2.160556  31084.181719     5
```

The final `sort_index` call sorts out the index-out-of-order problem (pun intended).

Comment: Right - I had managed that but the groups were not maintained. Should have mentioned it.

Comment: @sfjac Sorry, forgot to add the important bit in ;)

Comment: @sfjac Or `.sort_index(ascending=[True, False])` if you want finer control over how each level is sorted individually.

Comment: @sfjac Hmm, `sort_index` sorts the index, but does not care about the order of the ratings. In the end, a groupby + apply + sort_values might be more appropriate... :(

Comment: @sfjac Edit, never mind, just noticed it's exactly like yours. Sorry, I'm still not sure what your expected output is and how your current output is incorrect... can you help me understand better please?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163683/discussion-between-sfjac-and-cs).