# How to sort data using the groupby function in python?

Tags: pandas, sorting, pandas-groupby

I have struggles related to sorting data within groups. I have data of the average wage of nine different occupations grouped by SEX and country("GEO"). I would like to have a dataframe in which the occupations are ordered for each country and SEX following the average wage. 
So that I have for each country and SEX  9 occupations ordered by value.
This is what I have:

```
df

  wage   Country SEX  OCCUPATION
0   6   BELGIUM  M    Elementary
1   4   BELGIUM  M    POLICE 
2   6   BELGIUM  M    MANAGERS
3   8   BELGIUM  M    PROFESSIONALS
2   6   BELGIUM  F    PROFESSOIONALS     
3   8   BELGIUM  F    MANAGERS
4   7   BELGIUM  F    POLICE
5   5   FRANCE   M    POLICE
6   3   FRANCE   M    PROFESSIONALS
7   2   FRANCE   M    MANAGERS
```

But I would like to have this :

```
  wage   Country SEX  OCCUPATION
1   4   BELGIUM  M    POLICE 
0   6   BELGIUM  M    Elementary
2   6   BELGIUM  M    MANAGERS
3   8   BELGIUM  M    PROFESSIONALS
2   6   BELGIUM  F    PROFESSOIONALS     
4   7   BELGIUM  F    POLICE
3   8   BELGIUM  F    MANAGERS
7   2   FRANCE   M    MANAGERS
6   3   FRANCE   M    PROFESSIONALS
5   5   FRANCE   M    POLICE
```

In the end if possible I would like to assign a number from 1:number of occupation in the order of the wage.
 To illustrate:

```
  wage   Country SEX  OCCUPATION     ORDER
1   4   BELGIUM  M    POLICE            1
0   6   BELGIUM  M    Elementary        2
2   6   BELGIUM  M    MANAGERS          3
3   8   BELGIUM  M    PROFESSIONALS     4
2   6   BELGIUM  F    PROFESSOIONALS    1
4   7   BELGIUM  F    POLICE            2
3   8   BELGIUM  F    MANAGERS          3
7   2   FRANCE   M    MANAGERS          1
6   3   FRANCE   M    PROFESSIONALS     2
5   5   FRANCE   M    POLICE            3
```

This question  is related to:[pandas groupby sort within groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27842613/pandas-groupby-sort-within-groups). I have read this and it did not work : 
What I tried to achieve my desired df:

```
df=df.sort_values(["Country","SEX","wage"],ascending=False).groupby(["Country","SEX"])
```

Unfortunately python returns this instead of a dataframe:

```
<pandas.core.groupby.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy object at 0x0000022CC92DC668>

"GEO","SEX","occ", are all objects
obs_value is a float.
the df is a dataframe
```

I would be greatful if someone can help me out

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Only `df=df.sort_values(["Country","SEX","wage"],ascending=False)` should work for you. No need of `groupby`