# Pandas: Group by two parameters and sort by third parameter

Tags: python, pandas, sorting

I want to group my dataframe by two columns (Name and Budget) and then sort the aggregated results by a third parameter (Prio).

```
Name     Budget    Prio    Quantity
peter    A         2       12
         B         1       123
joe      A         3       34
         B         1       51
         C         2       43
```

I already checked this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27842613/pandas-groupby-sort-within-groups), which was very helpful and leads to the following output. However, I cannot manage sorting by the third parameter (Prio).

```
df_agg = df.groupby(['Name','Budget','Prio']).agg({'Quantity':sum})

g = df_agg['Quantity'].groupby(level=0, group_keys=False)

res = g.apply(lambda x: x.sort_values(ascending=True))
```

I would now like to sort the prio in ascending order within each of the groups. To get something like:

```
Name     Budget    Prio    Quantity
peter    B         1       123
         A         2       12
joe      B         1       51
         C         2       34
         A         3       43
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC,

```
df.groupby(['Name','Budget','Prio']).agg({'Quantity':sum}).sort_values(['Name','Prio'])
```

Output:

```
                   Quantity
Name  Budget Prio          
joe   B      1           51
      C      2            4
      A      3           34
peter B      1          123
      A      2           12
```

Comment: Thank you, that really helped! After this is done, is there any way to loop through the rows and access the specific values?

Comment: @maxiw46 Yes, you can use tuples to access a specific value.  `df_out.loc[('joe','A',3), 'Quantity']` returns 34.

Answer (score 1):

If you want only sort by `Prio`, you can use `sort_index`:

```
(df.groupby(['Name','Budget','Prio'])
   .agg({'Quantity':'sum'})
   .sort_index(level=['Name', 'Prio'],
                ascending=[False, True])
)
```

Output:

```
                   Quantity
Name  Budget Prio          
peter B      1          123
      A      2           12
joe   B      1           51
      C      2           43
      A      3           34
```