# How to sort values and index with a pivot table using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Giving this data:

```
 data = [{'Group1': 'A', 'Group2 date':'01/20/20', 'value1':0, 'value2':1},
         {'Group1': 'A', 'Group2 date':'01/25/20', 'value1':0, 'value2':3},
         {'Group1': 'A', 'Group2 date':'02/28/20', 'value1':0, 'value2':2},
         {'Group1': 'B', 'Group2 date':'01/25/20', 'value1':0, 'value2':1},
         {'Group1': 'B', 'Group2 date':'01/27/20', 'value1':2, 'value2':2},
         {'Group1': 'C', 'Group2 date':'01/29/20', 'value1':0, 'value2':5},
         {'Group1': 'C', 'Group2 date':'01/30/20', 'value1':2, 'value2':6}]
```

I have a pivot table created with pandas using:

```
pivot = pd.pivot_table(
  df,
  index=["Group1", "Group2 date"],
  values=["value1", "value2"],
  aggfunc={"value1":np.sum, "value2":np.sum},
)
```

and I'm getting a table like this:

```
                     value1  value2
Group1  Group2 date
A       01/20/20          0       1
        01/25/20          0       3
        01/28/20          0       2
B       01/25/20          0       1 
        01/27/20          2       2
C       01/29/20          0       5 
        01/30/20          2       6
```

But I need first the table sorted by "value2" with the highest values and then "Group2 date" be always descending to get something like:

```
                     value1  value2
Group1  Group2 date
C       01/30/20          2       6
        01/29/20          0       5 
A       01/28/20          0       2
        01/25/20          0       3
        01/20/20          0       1
B       01/27/20          2       2
        01/25/20          0       1
```

Is possible?, how?

Comment: is the sorting also by group?

Comment: "group1" column sort is not important.
"group1" rows with highest "value2" values should be on top and descending.
"Group2 date" should be sort descending inside every "group1" always.

Comment: take group1 - A : the dates are in descending order, but the values are not (2,3,1). Also, I believe the solution here should help : https://stackoverflow.com/a/36074520/7175713

Comment: The values for those days are ok, 01/28/20 should be 2, and same for the other. The values must not be changed, just the row position.
Unfortunately that solutions you showing me is not helping me

Answer (score 1):

This is what I could pull out: lemme know if it works for you. I used your data, just in a flattened form, as I was unsuccessful in reading in the multiindex.

```
data = '''

Group1  Group2_date value1  value2
A       01/20/20          0       1
A        01/25/20          0       3
A        01/28/20          0       2
B       01/25/20          0       1 
B        01/27/20          2       2
C       01/29/20          0       5 
C        01/30/20          2       6
   '''


df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), sep='\s+',engine='python')

#create a temp column, getting the max dates from each group

df['filler'] = df.groupby('Group1').Group2_date.transform('max')

#sort dataframe on filler and group1, so that the latest dates are at the top

df = df.sort_values(['filler','Group1'],ascending=False)

#list comprehension on a second groupby, this time using the filler and Group1
#note  the use of loc to flip the rows

M = [group.loc[::-1,] 
     for name, group in
     df.groupby(['filler','Group1'],sort=False)]

#concat and print result

outcome = pd.concat(M).drop('filler',axis=1)

    Group1  Group2_date value1  value2
6       C   01/30/20        2   6
5       C   01/29/20        0   5
2       A   01/28/20        0   2
1       A   01/25/20        0   3
0       A   01/20/20        0   1
4       B   01/27/20        2   2
3       B   01/25/20        0   1
```

Comment: Thanks, I just put outcome.set_index(["Group1", "Group2 date"], inplace=True) at the end to get what I was looking for, but I have realized that If I have more than two rows with the same "Group2 date" on the same "Group1" the "value1" and "value2" are not been taken in account to be summarized like the pivot_table does