# How to associate closest line to every given point in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, gis, geopandas, shapely

I have two Pandas DataFrames, the first one is named **Points** with columns '*longitude*' and '*latitude*' (i.e. geocoordinates); and, the second data frame is named **Links** with these columns: '*lon1*' & '*lat1*' for the first point and '*lon2*' & '*lat2*' for the second point then every pair of points given in each row creates a link/line. Also, for the **Links** DataFrame, it has a column named '*link_id*'.

Say, there are about 10 points and 4,000 links. How would I associate every given point to the closest link/line by returning the 'link_id' and appending it as an additional column named '*closest_link*' to the **Points** DataFrame?

Comment: The nature of stack overflow is geared towards specific questions about programming. This is more of a spatial analysis question, and it's unclear if you've already done any programming from for which people would suggest corrections and improvements. If you need someone to help you build a solution from scratch, I charge $75/hr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an approach that may work.  Consider:

1. Generating a cross product between the two dataframes **Points** and **Links** and ,
2. then applying a function to each *row* in that new DataFrame.
3. Find the least distance reported by the function for each group.

Let's call the new df, **PointsLinks**.

Here's some code that takes this approach:

```
import pandas as pd
import random        

Points = pd.DataFrame( [ [ 1,2 ], [ 3,4 ], [ 5,6 ] ], columns = [ 'longitude', 'latitude' ] )
Links = pd.DataFrame( [ [ 'Link1', ( 4,3 ) , ( -1, -2 ) ], [ 'Link2', (10,10) , ( -5, -5 ) ] ], columns = [ 'linkid', 'lon1&lat1', 'lon2&lat2' ] )

   
print(Points) 
print(Links)         

#Step 1:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53699012/performant-cartesian-product-cross-join-with-pandas
def cartesian_product_basic(left, right):
    return (         
       left.assign(key=1).merge(right.assign(key=1), on='key').drop('key', 1))
   
def DistanceToLink( pointlink ): 
  return random.randrange(10)  

PointsLinks = cartesian_product_basic(Points,Links)       
print( PointsLinks ) 

#Step 2: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26886653/pandas-create-new-column-based-on-values-from-other-columns-apply-a-function-o
PointsLinks['distance'] = PointsLinks.apply( lambda row : DistanceToLink(row), axis = 'columns' )


print( PointsLinks )

#Step 3:  Find the smallest distance per group https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27842613/pandas-groupby-sort-within-groups
closest = PointsLinks.sort_values( [ 'latitude', 'longitude', 'distance' ] , ascending = True ).groupby(  [ 'latitude', 'longitude'] ).head(1)

# Drop the unnecessary columns
closest.drop( columns = ['lon1&lat1','lon2&lat2','distance'] , inplace=True) 
print(closest)
```

Here are the dataframes created by the code:

Points:

```
   longitude  latitude
0          1         2
1          3         4
2          5         6
```

Links:

```
  linkid lon1&lat1 lon2&lat2
0  Link1    (4, 3)  (-1, -2)
1  Link2  (10, 10)  (-5, -5)
```

and then PointsLinks (after adding the distance column with apply():

```
   longitude  latitude linkid lon1&lat1 lon2&lat2  distance
0          1         2  Link1    (4, 3)  (-1, -2)         1
1          1         2  Link2  (10, 10)  (-5, -5)         6
2          3         4  Link1    (4, 3)  (-1, -2)         0
3          3         4  Link2  (10, 10)  (-5, -5)         9
4          5         6  Link1    (4, 3)  (-1, -2)         5
5          5         6  Link2  (10, 10)  (-5, -5)         1
```

I didn't implement `DistanceToLink`.  I just put a random number generator there.  Here's is what the first `pointlink` object looks like ( it is a Series representing a row):

```
longitude           1
latitude            2
linkid          Link1
lon1&lat1      (4, 3)
lon2&lat2    (-1, -2)
```

Now that you have the distance for each combination, you can find, and select, the PointLink pairs with the shortest distance (using [pandas groupby sort within groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27842613/pandas-groupby-sort-within-groups)):

```
closest = PointsLinks.sort_values( [ 'latitude', 'longitude', 'distance' ] , ascending = True ).groupby(  [ 'latitude', 'longitude'] ).head(1)
```

Here are the results:

```
   longitude  latitude linkid
0          1         2  Link1
2          3         4  Link1
5          5         6  Link2
```