# Sorting by columns using groupby pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have this data frame:
[image]

There is a column "CD" which has the city name, a column "FAC18" which is the number of people each line represents. And I have a column "S3P1" which is the academic level and is type int.
When I group it by "CD" with `hab_ciudad = cuestio.groupby('CD')["FAC18"].sum()` I get:

[image]

Where I have summed over "FAC18".
Now, I want also to group by academic level ("S3P1"). I want it to look like this:

[image]

where the columns are the values of "S3P1" and the sum is made over "FAC18".
I tried this code: `test = cuestio.groupby(['CD','S3P1'])["FAC18"].sum()`

But I get this:

[image]

What's the syntax to get the form I want?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pandas groupby sort within groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27842613/pandas-groupby-sort-within-groups)

Comment: can you add data that others can use instead of images please

Answer (score 0):

After your groupby, you need to use pivot:

```
test = cuestio.groupby(['CD','S3P1'])["FAC18"].sum()
test = test.pivot(index='CD', columns='S3P1', values='FAC18')
```