# Keep only largest interval in coordinates row in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe such as:

```
   Groups Name start end  sum
1      G1    A   451 954 1405
2      G1    B   451 951 1402
3      G1    C   451 969 1420
4      G1    D   463 870 1333
5      G1    E   463 888 1351
6      G1    X   230 450  680
7      G1    Z   229 450  681
8      G2    F   119 841  960
9      G2    G   118 842  960
10     G3    H   460 790 1250
11     G3    I   123 300 177
12     G4    J   343 878 1221
13     G4    K   343 878 1221
14     G4    L   320 862 1182
```

I would like for each Groups to keep only one interval representant (an interval meaning that `df.start` and `df.end` overlaps between rows), I explain:

For exemple, in the **G1** there are **2 intervals groups** :

**Interval 1** (with `min = 451` and `max = 969`):

```
Name start end sum
A    451   954 1405
B    451   951 1402
C    451   969 1420
D    463   870 1333
E    463   888 1351
```

Then I take the biggest `df.sum` (here `1420`)

and

**Interval2**  (with `min = 229` and `max = 450`)

```
Name start end  sum
X    230   450  680
Z    229   450  681
```

Then I take the biggest `df.sum` (here `681`)

If I do that for the whole dataframe I get:

```
   Groups Name start end  sum
3      G1    C   451 969 1420
7      G1    Z   229 450  681
9      G2    G   118 842  960
10     G3    H   460 790 1250
11     G3    I   123 300 177
12     G4    J   343 878 1221
```

Does someone have an idea?
Here are the data in dictionary format :

```
{'Groups Name start end  sum': {0: 'G1    A   451 954 1405', 1: 'G1    B   451 951 1402', 2: 'G1    C   451 969 1420', 3: 'G1    D   463 870 1333', 4: 'G1    E   463 888 1351', 5: 'G1    X   230 450  680', 6: 'G1    Z   229 450  681', 7: 'G2    F   119 841  960', 8: 'G2    G   118 842  960', 9: 'G3    H   460 790 1250', 10: 'G3    I   123 300 177', 11: 'G4    J   343 878 1221', 12: 'G4    K   343 878 1221', 13: 'G4    L   320 862 1182'}}
```

Comment: So, basically you want to get the `start` and `end` values for maximum `sum` value in each group (column `Groups`)? If so, have a look at [`.groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and group on column `Groups`. Then sort the values on column `sum` and take the first row (if sorted descending) or the last row (if sorted ascending). In addition, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27842613/pandas-groupby-sort-within-groups might be helpful

Comment: Hello, well it is not as simple as that, I also need to look at ```overlapping intervals``` of ```start and end``` within each groups, and then keep the ```longest Sum value```.

Comment: How do you decide between F and G? Their sum is the same.

Comment: Hello, well sorry I did not tel anything about that :  I take the first one.

Comment: @chippycentra For group `G4` I think there should be one more interval such that  `start=320 end=862`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can group the dataframe by both the `Groups` column and a new column representing the overlapping ranges. What you can do is first sort the dataframe by `Groups` and `end` (as well as `start` if there are duplicates in `end`).

```
df = df.sort_values(['Groups', 'end', 'start'])
```

Now, since we know the order of the rows, we can create the additional column mentioned above, let's call it `overlap`:

```
c1 = df['Groups'].shift() != df['Groups']
c2 = df['end'].shift() - df['start'] < 0
df['overlap'] = (c1 | c2).cumsum()
```

Current dataframe:

```
Groups Name  start  end   sum  overlap
7      G1    Z    229  450   681        1
6      G1    X    230  450   680        1
4      G1    D    463  870  1333        2
5      G1    E    463  888  1351        2
2      G1    B    451  951  1402        2
1      G1    A    451  954  1405        2
3      G1    C    451  969  1420        2
8      G2    F    119  841   960        3
9      G2    G    118  842   960        3
11     G3    I    123  300   177        4
10     G3    H    460  790  1250        5
14     G4    L    320  862  1182        6
12     G4    J    343  878  1221        6
13     G4    K    343  878  1221        6
```

Finally, we get the row with the maximum `sum` in each group using `groupby`.

```
df.sort_values(['sum'], ascending=False).groupby('overlap').first()
```

Result:

```
        Groups Name  start  end   sum
overlap                              
1           G1    Z    229  450   681
2           G1    C    451  969  1420
3           G2    F    119  841   960
4           G3    I    123  300   177
5           G3    H    460  790  1250
6           G4    J    343  878  1221
```

For the selection of rows where the `sum` is the same in a group, it is possible to use an additional column when sorting by the `sum` for second-level ordering. For example, if the order should be based on the original ordering of the rows a new `index` column can be added at the start by using `reset_index()`.