# the real order of sort().groupby() in polars?

Tags: python, python-polars

code in [user guider](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars-book/user-guide/dsl/groupby.html) is as follows:

```py
def get_person() -> pl.Expr:
    return pl.col("first_name") + pl.lit(" ") + pl.col("last_name")

q = (
    dataset.lazy()
    .sort("birthday")
    .groupby(["state"])
    .agg(
        [
            get_person().first().alias("youngest"),
            get_person().last().alias("oldest"),
        ]
    )
    .limit(5)
)

df = q.collect()
df
```

1 May the real order of `sort().groupby()` execute `groupby` first and then execute `sort`?  ,which is similar to `pandas`?
answer by @tvashtar about [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27842613/pandas-groupby-sort-within-groups) provides some tips.

Comment: I think you should ask one question per SO post. Can you split up this post in multiple questions?

Comment: okk，I have edited the Question.

Comment: I don't think pandas first does the `groupby`. Pandas does not reorder operations.

Comment: I remove those content. The osf is a good place to ask questions, but it seems to be focused on a single question, so maybe it's not a good channel for "continue discussion".My original question has been answered, although subsequent study has made me think that there may be a little problem with the original answer( thans for his hard work), but it seems to be more difficult to achieve a quick contact and communication with the original author.

Answer (score 0):

The logical order of a `polars` query is the order you read it from top to bottom.

```py
q = (
    dataset.lazy()
    .sort("birthday")
    .groupby(["state"])
    .agg(
        [
            get_person().first().alias("youngest"),
            get_person().last().alias("oldest"),
        ]
    )
    .limit(5)
)
```

This snippets has the following order of operations `sort -> groupby/agg ->  limit`.

Note that `polars` may choose to execute the query in a different order **IFF** the outcome is the same. This might be done for performance reasons.

> 1 May the real order of sort().groupby() execute groupby first and then execute sort? ,which is similar to pandas?

I don't think that `pandas` does this. The result would be incorrect if it did. The outcome of a `first` aggregation changes by sorting, so if we would decide to do the sort after the groupby operation, we would have changed the outcome of the query and thus this optimization is invalid.

Comment: so it doesn't group by `state` and sort the `birthday` within group. If that's true, I think it may be not a good example for user guide.

Comment: Why isn't it a good example? I don't think the user guide claimed it sorted the birthday within that group.

Comment: But if it groups by `state` but otherwise preserves the order of the original data then this is the same as sorting by `birthday` within `state`? This clearly seems like what they suggest is done in the docs: https://pola-rs.github.io/polars-book/user-guide/dsl/groupby.html#sorting

Comment: Also the docs states the following: _"Let's say that we want to get the names of the oldest and youngest politicians per state."_ So if the people are __not__ sorted by `birthday` within the `state` in the example then it is a truly bad example.

Comment: It first sorts the data and then groups by `state`. This will ensure that the within the groupby aggregation is sorted.

Comment: Yes, so then the user guide claims it sorted the `birthday` within that group, `state`, or at least something equivalent (within the groupby aggregation is sorted -- order does not matter). This is contrary to your earlier comment: _"I don't think the user guide claimed it sorted the birthday within that group"_ unless I am miss-understanding something? Also this seems to go against the remark: "_The result would be incorrect if it did._" The result would be the same whether it a) sorts and groups but preserve order or b) groups and sort within group.

Comment: Could you make a proposal PR on the user guide for better wording?

Comment: I am not saying the user guide is wrong or confusing but that your comments and answer here seem contradictory.