# Group by, sort, cumsum normalization pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, group-by, cumsum

How to make this work?
`df['sum_greater_then'] = df.groupby(['scan_number', 'raw_file]).sort_values('rank', ascending=False)['intensity'].cumsum()`

I need to normalize the data. For this I first need to add intensities up based on their rank in the spectra. One spectra is when 'scan_number' and 'raw_file' don't change.

| intensity | rank | scan_number | raw_file |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1,057 | 3 | 3006 | 01640a_BA5 |
| 4,03 | 1 | 3006 | 01640a_BA5 |
| 2,05 | 2 | 3006 | 01640a_BA5 |

These are the calculations, which I need to do:

Rank 1: (4,03 + 2,05 + 1,057) / total = 7,137/7,137 = 1

Rank 2: (2,05 + 1,057) / total = 0,435

Rank 3: 1,057 / total = 0,148

There are other columns in the dataframe, I don't need them for this specific calculation though.

I already ranked each intensity, calculated the total and created a column each for those values. I just need to add up the right intensities to divide them by total and get the normalized value in the end.

This doesn't work as well
`df['sum_greater_then'] = df.groupby(['scan_number', 'raw_file]).apply(lambda x: x.sort_values('rank', ascending=False)['intensity'].cumsum())`

Answer (score 0):

This is a little clunky, but I believe achieves what you want.  [First do the sort](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36074520/13386979) based on the `rank`, then groupby and take the cumulative sum.  Afterwards, transform the data to normalize by the total sum:

```
x = df.sort_values('rank', ascending=False).groupby(['scan_number', 'raw_file'])['intensity'].cumsum()
df['sum_greater_than'] = x
df['sum_greater_than'] = df.groupby(['scan_number', 'raw_file'])['sum_greater_than'].transform(lambda x : x / x.max())
```

Here's the final result:

```
   intensity  rank  scan_number    raw_file  sum_greater_than
0      1.057     3         3006  01640a_BA5          0.148101
1      4.030     1         3006  01640a_BA5          1.000000
2      2.050     2         3006  01640a_BA5          0.435337
```

I guess you can do this in one (long) line if you use a custom `apply` function:

```
df['sum_greater_than'] = df.sort_values('rank', ascending=False).groupby(['scan_number', 'raw_file'])['intensity'].apply(lambda x: x.cumsum() / x.sum())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df = df.sort_values('rank',ascending=False)
df['sum_intensities']=df.groupby(['scan_number','raw_file'])['intensity'].cumsum()
```

Pandas groupby does not support sort_values().

Step 1 : Sort based on a column(here 'rank')

Step 2 : Groupby and take cumulative sum and save in a variable
[image: output]

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `rank` unless the calculation for rank is more complex than in this example. Just see `sort_valuies` then `groupby`:

Data set up:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'val': np.random.randint(low=1, high=100, size=10),
                   'name': ['a']*5+['b']*5})
df.sort_values(by=['name', 'val'], ascending=[True, True], ignore_index=True, inplace=True)
```

**If you have small data:**

```
# cumsum
df['cumsum'] = df.groupby('name')[['val']].cumsum()

# cumprod:
df['grsum'] = df.groupby('name')[['val']].transform(lambda g: g.sum())
df['cumprod'] = df['cumsum']/df['grsum']

df
```

**If have a big data:** then using `transform` will slow down a lot, instead `merge` method make it much faster

```
# sub dataframe sum by group
dfsum = df.groupby('name')[['val']].sum().reset_index().rename(columns={'val':'sum'})

# merge
df = pd.merge(df, dfsum, how='left', on='name')
```

The rest is similar to above