# Python Panda - getting top 3 max values from Column 3 grouped by Column 1 displaying also Column 2

Tags: python, pandas

**Here is the data:**

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| category1 | subcat1 | 10 |
| category1 | subcat2 | 15 |
| category1 | subcat3 | 1 |
| category1 | subcat4 | 23 |
| category2 | subcat1 | 10 |
| category2 | subcat2 | 99 |
| category2 | subcat3 | 23 |
| category2 | subcat4 | 12 |
| category2 | subcat5 | 10 |
| category2 | subcat6 | 11 |
| category2 | subcat7 | 45 |
| category2 | subcat8 | 105 |
| category3 | subcat1 | 2 |
| category3 | subcat2 | 9 |
| category3 | subcat3 | 14 |
| category3 | subcat4 | 25 |
| ... | ... | ... |

**What i want is something like this** (max3 subcat + values per category):

```py
category1:
          subcat1  10
          subcat2  15
          subcat3  10
category2:
          subcat2  99
          subcat7  45
          subcat8  105
category3:
          subcat2  9
          subcat3  14
          subcat4  25
```

**Many thanks in advance.**

I´m fairly new here, hope for your understanding while reading this explaination. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for your demo data:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['category1', 'category1','category1', 'category1', 'category2', 'category2','category2', 'category2', 'category2', 'category2','category2', 'category2', 'category3', 'category3','category3', 'category3'],
                  'col2': ['subcat1', 'subcat2', 'subcat3', 'subcat4', 'subcat1', 'subcat2', 'subcat3', 'subcat4', 'subcat5', 'subcat6', 'subcat7', 'subcat8', 'subcat1', 'subcat2', 'subcat3', 'subcat4'],
                  'col3': [10, 15, 1, 23, 10, 99, 23, 12, 10, 11, 45, 105, 2, 9, 14, 25]})
print(df)

    col1    col2    col3
0   category1   subcat1 10
1   category1   subcat2 15
2   category1   subcat3 1
3   category1   subcat4 23
4   category2   subcat1 10
5   category2   subcat2 99
6   category2   subcat3 23
7   category2   subcat4 12
8   category2   subcat5 10
9   category2   subcat6 11
10  category2   subcat7 45
11  category2   subcat8 105
12  category3   subcat1 2
13  category3   subcat2 9
14  category3   subcat3 14
15  category3   subcat4 25
```

**Here is the solution offered by [joris](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27844045/9575303) in another question:**

```py
df_agg = df.groupby(['col1', 'col2']).agg({'col3': sum})
a = df_agg['col3'].groupby('col1', group_keys=False).nlargest(3)

print(a)
col1       col2   
category1  subcat4     23
           subcat2     15
           subcat1     10
category2  subcat8    105
           subcat2     99
           subcat7     45
category3  subcat4     25
           subcat3     14
           subcat2      9
```

Comment: Thank you, this solution linked is what I was looking for. On the way to there, I also discovered another possibility to do so, using pandas pivot tables. I´m giving here the link, just in case someone has a similar issue:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is work around, I still think there is a better way of doing it, but this should help you out for now:

```py
result = pd.DataFrame()
for item in df['category'].unique():
    result = result.append(df[df.category == item].nlargest(3, 'value'))
```

Basically you use the `nlargest` method on a sub-dataframe for each category, in a kind of manual groupby function, because it is not supported on groupby objects.

Comment: Hi Yashar, thanks for the hint!
I will try this a bit later today and see if I can get to make it work :)