# Grouby followed by counts as new column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I wanted to perform a groupby on an account ID and then perform a count of values after group by and give their counts as a new column.
How can I do it in pandas.

Eg:

```
Account Id     Values
1                     Open
2                     Closed
1                     Open
3                     Closed
2                     Open
```

Output must be:

```
Account Id    Open    Closed
1                      2             0
2                      1             1
3                      0             1
```

Comment: Sorry about the initial example's format, had posted the question from mobile.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `groupby` and `value_counts` to get the initial counts you want.  Then unstack the multiindex to get a DataFrame and set null values to 0 to get the final results:

```
import pandas as pd

# Defining DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(index=range(5))
df['Account Id'] = [1, 2, 1, 3, 2]
df['Values'] = ['Open', 'Closed', 'Open', 'Closed', 'Open']

grouped = df.groupby('Account Id')['Values'].value_counts()
# Remove the multiindex present
grouped = grouped.unstack()
# Set null values to 0
result = grouped.where(pd.notnull(grouped), 0)
```

Output of result:

```
        Closed  Open
Account Id      
1           0   2
2           1   1
3           1   0
```

(Sorry, I'm not sure how to properly represent the DataFrame)

Comment: I did something similar but want to get it as a data frame so that I can join with other existing data frames.

Comment: The result should be a dataframe. The intermediate 'grouped' is a multiindex series. The unstack changes it into a dataframe by making it single index. (Sorry I can't format this properly, on mobile now.)

Comment: .reset_index() helped!
Reference : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10373660/converting-a-pandas-groupby-object-to-dataframe

Comment: Could you clarify exactly what it helped with, I'm slightly confused! The output of my code should be exactly the dataframe you requested.

Answer (score 0):

This would also return the dataframe for groupby object:

```
grouped_df = df.groupby(["Account Id","Values"])
grouped_df.size().reset_index(name = "Count")
```