# Aggregate function to data frame in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, aggregate-functions, series

I want to create a dataframe from an aggregate function. I thought that it would create by default a dataframe as this solution states, but it creates a series and I don't know why ([Converting a Pandas GroupBy object to DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10373660/converting-a-pandas-groupby-object-to-dataframe)).

The dataframe is from Kaggle's San Francisco Salaries. My code:

```
df=pd.read_csv('Salaries.csv')

in: type(df)
out: pandas.core.frame.DataFrame

in: df.head()
out: EmployeeName   JobTitle    TotalPay    TotalPayBenefits    Year    Status  2BasePay    2OvertimePay    2OtherPay   2Benefits   2Year
0   NATHANIEL FORD  GENERAL MANAGER-METROPOLITAN TRANSIT AUTHORITY  567595.43   567595.43   2011    NaN 167411.18   0.00    400184.25   NaN 2011-01-01
1   GARY JIMENEZ    CAPTAIN III (POLICE DEPARTMENT) 538909.28   538909.28   2011    NaN 155966.02   245131.88   137811.38   NaN 2011-01-01
2   ALBERT PARDINI  CAPTAIN III (POLICE DEPARTMENT) 335279.91   335279.91   2011    NaN 212739.13   106088.18   16452.60    NaN 2011-01-01
3   CHRISTOPHER CHONG   WIRE ROPE CABLE MAINTENANCE MECHANIC    332343.61   332343.61   2011    NaN 77916.00    56120.71    198306.90   NaN 2011-01-01
4   PATRICK GARDNER DEPUTY CHIEF OF DEPARTMENT,(FIRE DEPARTMENT)    326373.19   326373.19   2011    NaN 134401.60   9737.00 182234.59   NaN 2011-01-01

in: df2=df.groupby(['JobTitle'])['TotalPay'].mean()
type(df2)
out: pandas.core.series.Series
```

I want df2 to be a dataframe with the columns 'JobTitle' and 'TotalPlay'

Comment: It would help if you included a code example and some data in that code.

Comment: ok, code and data added

Comment: What I mean by "data" is that if you have some copy paste bit of code read which includes creating your data, it is more likely that someone will help modyfining it. I cannot perform df.groupby on your posting :-)

Comment: i appreciate it, although piRSquared nailed it perfectly already with his answer :)

Comment: Yes, he did. But there is always something one can learn for the next question ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Breaking down your code:

```
df2 = df.groupby(['JobTitle'])['TotalPay'].mean()
```

The `groupby` is fine.  It's the `['TotalPay']` that is the misstep.  That is telling the `groupby` to only execute the the `mean` function on the `pd.Series` `df['TotalPay']` for each group defined in `['JobTitle']`.  Instead, you want to refer to this column with `[['TotalPay']]`.  Notice the double brackets.  Those double brackets say `pd.DataFrame`.

---

#### Recap

```
df2 = df2=df.groupby(['JobTitle'])[['TotalPay']].mean()
```