# pandas: create single size & sum columns after group by multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe where I am doing groupby on 3 columns and aggregating the sum and size of the numerical columns. After running the code

```
df = pd.DataFrame.groupby(['year','cntry', 'state']).agg(['size','sum'])
```

I am getting something like below:

[image: Image of datafram]

Now I want to split my size sub columns from main columns and create only single size column but want to keep the sum columns under main column headings. I have tried different approaches but not successful.
These are the methods I have tried but unable to get things working for me:

[How to count number of rows in a group in pandas group by object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19384532/how-to-count-number-of-rows-in-a-group-in-pandas-group-by-object)

[Converting a Pandas GroupBy object to DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10373660/converting-a-pandas-groupby-object-to-dataframe)

Will be grateful to if anyone can help me with this one.

Regards,

Answer (score 9, accepted):

***Setup***

```
d1 = pd.DataFrame(dict(
        year=np.random.choice((2014, 2015, 2016), 100),
        cntry=['United States' for _ in range(100)],
        State=np.random.choice(states, 100),
        Col1=np.random.randint(0, 20, 100),
        Col2=np.random.randint(0, 20, 100),
        Col3=np.random.randint(0, 20, 100),
    ))

df = d1.groupby(['year', 'cntry', 'State']).agg(['size', 'sum'])
df
```

[image]

---

***Answer***
Easiest way would have been to only run `size` after `groupby`

```
d1.groupby(['year', 'cntry', 'State']).size()

year  cntry          State        
2014  United States  California       10
                     Florida           9
                     Massachusetts     8
                     Minnesota         5
2015  United States  California        9
                     Florida           7
                     Massachusetts     4
                     Minnesota        11
2016  United States  California        8
                     Florida           8
                     Massachusetts    11
                     Minnesota        10
dtype: int64
```

---

To use the calculated `df`

```
df.xs('size', axis=1, level=1)
```

[image]

And that would be useful if the `size` were different for each column.  But because the `size` column is the same for `['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3']`, we can just do

```
df[('Col1', 'size')]

year  cntry          State        
2014  United States  California       10
                     Florida           9
                     Massachusetts     8
                     Minnesota         5
2015  United States  California        9
                     Florida           7
                     Massachusetts     4
                     Minnesota        11
2016  United States  California        8
                     Florida           8
                     Massachusetts    11
                     Minnesota        10
Name: (Col1, size), dtype: int64
```

---

***Combined View 1***

```
pd.concat([df[('Col1', 'size')].rename('size'),
           df.xs('sum', axis=1, level=1)], axis=1)
```

[image]

---

***Combined View 2***

```
pd.concat([df[('Col1', 'size')].rename(('', 'size')),
           df.xs('sum', axis=1, level=1, drop_level=False)], axis=1)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi piRSquared,
Thanks for the detailed reply but I have two concern with the code above.
First: When I run the code 
df.xs('size', axis=1, level=1) 
I am getting the following error:
ValueError: No axis named 1 for object type <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
Second that I need to keep the sum columns under col1, col2 & col3 as well. 
Can you please tell me how I can fix that?
Regards

Comment: @Baig The first value error you are getting is from `df` not being a dataframe, but a series instead.  Please check your variables.  If `d1` is defined as above and `df = d1.groupby(['year', 'cntry', 'State']).agg(['size', 'sum'])` then this error is impossible.  Second concern, I'll address by updating the post.

Answer (score 2):

piRSquared beat me to it but if you must do it this way and want to keep the alignment with columns and sum or size underneath you could reindex the columns to remove the size value and then add in a new column to contain the size value.

For example:

```
group = df.groupby(['year', 'cntry','state']).agg(['sum','size'])
mi = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['Col1','Col2','Col3'],['sum']])
group = group.reindex_axis(mi,axis=1)
sizes = df.groupby('state').size().values
group['Tot'] = 0
group.columns = group.columns.set_levels(['sum','size'], level=1)
group.Tot.size = sizes
```

It will end up looking like this:

```
                 Col1 Col2 Col3  Tot
                  sum  sum  sum size
year cntry State
2015 US    CA      20    0    4    1
           FL      40    3    5    1
           MASS     8    1    3    1
           MN      12    2    3    1
```