# Pandas DataFrame to Dictionary conversion

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe, which I want to convert to a dictionary in such a way that col1 becomes the key and col2 becomes the value. Also, there can be multiple occurrences of a value in 1st col, in which case  I want to store the counts in the form of a list corresponding to that value of col1 as key.
So basically how can I perform this conversion -

 area  count

10       7 
 10       3 
 10       1 
 20       5 
 30       2 
 30       1 
 40       3

{ 
'10' : [7,3,1],
'20' : '5',
'30' : [2,1],
'40' : 3 

}

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try this: `df.groupby('area')['count'].apply(list).to_dict()`

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks! 
I had another use case: What if there is a 3rd column indicating probability and I want to sort the counts by this probability value before storing them as list? Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understood your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41085938/pandas-dataframe-to-dictionary-conversion/41086020#comment69377150_41085938) correctly you can do it this way:

```
In [35]: df
Out[35]:
   area  count  probability
0    10      7     0.116754
1    10      3     0.703845
2    10      1     0.368201
3    20      5     0.550190
4    30      2     0.037654
5    30      1     0.379534
6    40      3     0.320877

In [36]: df.sort_values('probability', ascending=False).groupby('area')['count'].apply(list).to_dict()
Out[36]: {10: [3, 1, 7], 20: [5], 30: [1, 2], 40: [3]}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted to do!Thanks! Can we convert this dictionary back to dataframe?

Comment: @user3024292, you are welcome! It's going to be bit tricky to convert it back to DF - you'd better ask a new question with small data samples (especially for expected DF)

Comment: Can't ask another question before 90min! So I'll try to explain this here instead.For eg if I dont do apply(list).to_dict() I get the following output: \n
df.sort_values('probability', ascending=False).groupby('area')['count']

<pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy object at 0x184e11e90>

 Can we convert the groupby object to a dataframe?

Comment: @user3024292, it's not clear to me what kind of result DF do you expect to get when converting `groupby` object to DF...

Comment: Found the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10373660/converting-a-pandas-groupby-object-to-dataframe
Thanks anyways!

Comment: @user3024292, you may also want to check examples in Pandas docs: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#groupby