# Groupby and count() on dataframe having two categorical variables

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataset, which I need to groupby() and find the count of each unique combination.

```
    body-style        make
0  convertible  alfa-romeo
1  convertible  alfa-romeo
2    hatchback  alfa-romeo
3        sedan        audi
4        sedan        audi
```

My need is to produce an output as shown below:

```
             make   body-style   count
0     alfa-romero  convertible       2
1     alfa-romero    hatchback       1
2            audi    sedan           2
```

Tried the below code:

```
body = pd.DataFrame({'make':['alfa-romeo','alfa-romeo','alfa-romeo','audi','audi'], 'body-style':['convertible','convertible','hatchback','sedan','sedan']})

body.groupby(by=['make','body-style'], as_index=False).count()
```

This aggregation throws up "*list index out of range*" error. However, when I remove either of the columns from groupby clause, it is able to give me counts grouped by the remaining column.

If I remove *as_index=False*, there is no error, but the resultant object will have both columns - *make* and *body-style* as part of the index and there won'nt be any count data.

I can add another column to the datframe, fill it with 1s and take a `sum()` instead of `count()` on the groupby. But would like to know if there is a cleaner way to do this.

Comment: Check my answer with this problem from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32307259/2901002)

Comment: If you add both make and body style as grouper, there is nothing left to count. Count is a special method that tallies non null values in a column. What you want is probably `.size()`

Comment: This seems like a very good question to me. It has a reproducible example, op's attempt, clear definition of the problem yet it is downvoted. Is there something I missed?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you can use `GroupBy.count()` only if you have at least one column that hasn't been used for grouping.

In case you group by all columns in the DF - use `.size()` instead:

```
In [119]: body.groupby(['make','body-style']).size().reset_index(name='count')
Out[119]:
         make   body-style  count
0  alfa-romeo  convertible      2
1  alfa-romeo    hatchback      1
2        audi        sedan      2
```

Comment: Could you please clarify why your solution works and the code in the question doesn't?

Comment: @SashaTsukanov, sure, added a short description...

Comment: Say if there were only 2 body style for every make, style-A and style-B. How can we get count of each of the type in the same column from the previous dataframe? The output will be:

make         body-style-A count body-style-B count

alfa-romero               2                              1 
audi                                1                              1