# Passing pandas groupby result to html in a pretty way

Tags: python

I wonder how could I pass python pandas `groupby` result to html formatted such as printed in console. Pic below. `to_html` does not work because It says that

> Series object has no attribute to_html()

[image]

The one on the left is from console the one from the right is from my html view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`reset_index()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10373660/converting-a-pandas-groupby-object-to-dataframe) on your GroupBy object will enable you to treat it as a normal DataFrame i.e. apply `to_html` to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can make sure you output a DataFrame, even if the output is a single series.

I can think of two ways.

```py
results_series = df[column_name]  # your results, returns a series
# method 1: select column from list, as a DataFrame
results_df = df[[column_name]] # returns a DataFrame
# method 2: after selection, generate a new DataFrame
results_df = pd.DataFrame(results_series)
# then, export to html
results_df.to_html('output.html')
```