# Pandas stack groupby to DataFrame MultiIndex without aggregating

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Several questions posted about transforming pandas groupby object to DataFrame seem to involve aggregation, as e.g. `count()` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10373660/converting-a-pandas-groupby-object-to-dataframe).

Can a groupby object be converted to a DataFrame *without* aggregating, where the group names become level 0 of a MultiIndex? and can this process be iterated?

```
from pandas import DataFrame as DF

df = DF.from_dict({'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3, 'd':4, 'e':5}, orient='index')
```

would like the output of the grouping:

```
df.groupby(lambda x: df[0][x]%2)
```

converted to this form:

```
DF.from_dict({0:{'b':2,'d':4},1:{'a':1,'c':3,'e':5}},orient='index').stack().to_frame()
```

[image]

(besides the point, why are values converted to floats?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `pd.concat`, it accepts a dictionary:

```
pd.concat({k: v for k, v in df.groupby(lambda x: df.loc[x, 0] % 2)})

     0
0 b  2
  d  4
1 a  1
  c  3
  e  5
```

Iterate over each group and build your dictionary. The dictionary can be constructed using a [dictionary comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/).

---

A slightly faster solution not involving a callable can be done with,

```
pd.concat({k: v for k, v in df.groupby(df.iloc[:,0] % 2)})

     0
0 b  2
  d  4
1 a  1
  c  3
  e  5
```

---

If you need, do this again and again, try a function,

```
def add_level(df, grouper):
    return pd.concat({k: v for k, v in df.groupby(by=grouper)})

r = add_level(df, df.iloc[:,0] % 3)
add_level(r, r.iloc[:, 0] % 2)

       0
0 1 d  4
  2 b  2
1 0 c  3
  1 a  1
  2 e  5
```

Comment: Thanks that works. I was going to further ask in the Q, how to iterate the stack. Eg, if ` df.loc[x, 0] % 3` gives level-0 index [0,1,2], would like to further group this index by %2 to get a 3-level MultiIndex, what's the appropriate lambda?

Comment: @alancalvitti It seems like you can just repeat this process twice, once for %3 and the second for %2.

Comment: But now `df.loc[x, 0]` won't work as the groupings are generated based on the index, not the values.

Answer (score 2):

Using `assign` chain with `set_index`

```
df.assign(indexlevel=np.arange(len(df))%2).\
    set_index('indexlevel',append=True).\
      swaplevel(0,1).\
       sort_index(level=0)
Out[30]: 
              0
indexlevel     
0          a  1
           c  3
           e  5
1          b  2
           d  4
```

Comment: Upvote for effort but that's a long way to go for a simple procedure.