# Create binary column in pandas dataframe based on priority

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe that looks something like this:

```
Item    Status
123     B
123     BW
123     W 
123     NF
456     W
456     BW
789     W
789     NF
000     NF
```

And I need to create a new column `Value` which will be either 1 or 0 depending on the values in the `Item` and `Status` columns. The assignment of the value 1 is prioritized by this order: `B`, `BW`, `W`, `NF`. So, using the sample dataframe above, the result should be:

```
Item    Status    Value
123     B         1
123     BW        0
123     W         0
123     NF        0
456     W         0
456     BW        1
789     W         1
789     NF        0
000     NF        1
```

Using Python 3.7.

Comment: How does the `Item` column play a role in this?  Do you assign only one `1` value per `Item`, based on the order of priority in `Status`?

Comment: If there is only one instance of a certain item in the `Item` column, it should be `1` by default. However, when there is more than one occurrence of an item, then, based on the `Status` and the priority, there should be a corresponding value of either `1` or `0`. Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking your original dataframe as input `df` dataframe, the following code will produce your desired output:

```
#dictionary assigning order of priority to status values
priority_map = {'B':1,'BW':2,'W':3,'NF':4}

#new temporary column that converts Status values to order of priority values
df['rank'] = df['Status'].map(priority_map)

#create dictionary with Item as key and lowest rank value per Item as value
lowest_val_dict = df.groupby('Item')['rank'].min().to_dict()

#new column that assigns the same Value to all rows per Item
df['Value'] = df['Item'].map(lowest_val_dict)

#replace Values where rank is different with 0's
df['Value'] = np.where(df['Value'] == df['rank'],1,0)

#delete rank column
del df['rank']
```

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer an approach where the status is an ordered [`pd.Categorical`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Categorical.html), because a) that's what it is and b) it's much more readable: if you have that, you just compare if a value is equal to the `max` of its group:

```
df['Status'] = pd.Categorical(df['Status'], categories=['NF', 'W', 'BW', 'B'],
                              ordered=True)
df['Value'] = df.groupby('Item')['Status'].apply(lambda x: (x == x.max()).astype(int))

#   Item Status  Value
#0   123      B      1
#1   123     BW      0
#2   123      W      0
#3   123     NF      0
#4   456      W      0
#5   456     BW      1
#6   789      W      1
#7   789     NF      0
#8     0     NF      1
```

Comment: Last should be better by `df['Value'] = df.groupby('Item')['Status'].transform('max').eq(df['Status']).astype(int)`

Comment: You could consider it better, since it is a tiny bit faster for very large dataframes, although I'd argue it is less readable. Anyway, good comment, intersting approach

Answer (score 0):

I might be able to help you conceptually, by explaining some steps that I would do:

1. Create the new column Value, and fill it with zeros `np.zeros()` or `pd.fillna()`
2. Group the dataframe by Item with `groupby = pd.groupby('Item')`
3. Iterate through all the groups founds `for name, group in groupby:`
4. By using a simple function with if's, a custom priority queue, custom sorting criteria, or any other preferred method, determine which **entry has higher priority** " *by this value 1 is prioritized by this order: B, BW, W, NF* ", and **assign a value of 1 to it's Value column** `group.loc[entry]['Value'] == 0`

   Let's say we are looking at group '123':

   ```
    Item    Status    Value
    -------------------------
    123     B         0 (before 0, after 1)
    123     BW        0
    123     W         0
    123     NF        0
   ```

   Because the row `[123, 'B', 0]` had the highest priority based on your criteria, you change it to `[123, 'B',  1]`
5. When finished, create the dataframe back from the groupby object, and you're done. You have a lot of possibilities for doing that, might check here: [Converting a Pandas GroupBy object to DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10373660/converting-a-pandas-groupby-object-to-dataframe)