# How to turn a pandas df into a dictionary with subgroups

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
d = {'country': ['America','America','America','America','Canada','Canada','Canada','Canada'],\
     'city': ['New York','New York','San Francisco','San Francisco',u'Montréal',u'Montréal','Toronto','Toronto'],\
     'landmark': ['Statue of Liberty', 'Empire State Building','Golden Gate Bridge',\
                  'Mission District','Biodome', 'Parc Laurier', 'CN Tower', 'Royal Ontario Museum']}
pd.DataFrame(data = d)
```

I want it to be a dict like this:

```
all_options = {
    'America': {
        'New York': ['Statue of Liberty', 'Empire State Building'],
        'San Francisco': ['Golden Gate Bridge', 'Mission District'],
    },
    'Canada': {
        u'Montréal': ['Biodome', 'Parc Laurier'],
        'Toronto': ['CN Tower', 'Royal Ontario Museum'],
    }
}
```

Comment: This may be useful for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10373660/converting-a-pandas-groupby-output-from-series-to-dataframe/32307259#32307259

Comment: Also this one: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-dataframe-groupby/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do with a `dict comprehension` like:

```
all_options = {country: grp.groupby('city')['landmark'].apply(list).to_dict()
               for country, grp in df.groupby('country')}
```

[out]

```
{'America': {'New York': ['Statue of Liberty', 'Empire State Building'],
  'San Francisco': ['Golden Gate Bridge', 'Mission District']},
 'Canada': {'Montréal': ['Biodome', 'Parc Laurier'],
  'Toronto': ['CN Tower', 'Royal Ontario Museum']}}
```

---

Or if you prefer the more explicit approach, this is equivalent to the `for` loop:

```
all_options = {}

for country, grp in df.groupby('country'):
    all_options[country] = grp.groupby('city')['landmark'].apply(list).to_dict()
```

---

Useful links for the above include, [`DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html), [`Series.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) and [`Series.to_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_dict.html)