# Creating a weighted network from co-occurence of hashtags from a dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, networkx, sna, network-analysis

I have a dataframe of tweets where one of the columns has information about the hashtags contained in the tweet (tweets_df.hashtags) as a list of hashtags.

```
>> tweets_df.hashtags

0                                       [dkpol]
1                              [dkmedier, fv19]
2                    [dkpol, dksocial, dkidræt]
3                                       [dkpol]
4        [røgfrifremtid, folketingsvalg, dkpol]
5                           [biblioteker, fv19]
6                                       [dkpol]
7                                        [fv19]
8              [dkpol, fv19, løgner, mandsling]
9                               [dkpol, valg19]
10                                [dkpol, fv19]
```

From this I need to create a graph object to export to Gephi.
What I want is each hashtag as a node, and each co-occurrence as an un-directed connection between the hashtags.

So far I've tried the following approach:

```
col1 = []
col2 = []
for index, row in tweets_df.head(10).iterrows():
    hashtags=row['hashtags']
    hashtags_len = len(hashtags)
    for n in list(itertools.combinations(hashtags, 2)):
        col1.append(n[0])
        col2.append(n[1])
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(col1, col2)))
```

which gives an edgelist like

```
>> df
             0               1
0         dkmedier            fv19
1            dkpol        dksocial
2            dkpol         dkidræt
3         dksocial         dkidræt
4    røgfrifremtid  folketingsvalg
5    røgfrifremtid           dkpol
6   folketingsvalg           dkpol
7      biblioteker            fv19
8            dkpol            fv19
9            dkpol          løgner
10           dkpol       mandsling
11            fv19          løgner
12            fv19       mandsling
13          løgner       mandsling
14           dkpol          valg19
```

and from that creating my network through
    g = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, 0, 1)

This gives me a network with the connections I need, however it doesn't give me weights based on multiple occurences of same connection.

If somebody can help me with this it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`from_pandas_edgelist` accepts an `edge_attr` parameter that would allow you to set a weight. So all you need to do is create another column in your dataframe with a count of the unique co-occurrences of your tweets, and specify that as your `edge_attr`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx

# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# create some fake data
nodes = 'abcde'
edges = [(nodes[ii], nodes[jj]) for ii, jj in np.random.randint(len(nodes), size=(100, 2))]

# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# create a data frame with columns source, target, count

# you probably don't care about which tweet was named first, so before
# we aggreate edges, we need to sort them
edges = [sorted(edge) for edge in edges]

# create pandas dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(edges, columns=['source', 'target'])

# aggregate repeated edges
# c.f. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10373660/converting-a-pandas-groupby-output-from-series-to-dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'count' : df.groupby(['source', 'target']).size()}).reset_index()

# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# create a weighted network and draw

g = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, source='source', target='target', edge_attr='count')

pos = nx.spring_layout(g)
nx.draw(g, pos, with_labels=True)
labels = nx.get_edge_attributes(g, 'count')
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(g, pos, edge_labels=labels)
plt.show()
```

[image]