# Pandas groupby count and fill none count as 0

Tags: python, pandas

here is MRE:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"hour":[1,2,2,3,3,6,6,6], "location":["a","a", "b","b","c","c","c","c"]})
```

which looks like this:

```
    hour    location
0   1         a
1   2         a
2   2         b
3   3         b
4   3         c
5   6         c
6   6         c
7   6         c
```

When I groupby hour and count number of time each hour occured I get

```
df.groupby(["hour"]).count()

>>>  location
hour    
1        1
2        2
3        2
6        3
```

In want to fill hours 4 and 5 and set its count to 0.

Here is what I desire:

```
    location
hour    
1       1
2       2
3       2
4       0
5       0
6       3
```

Previously I've used

```
df.groupby(["hour", "location"]).count().unstack(fill_value=0).stack()
```

Which I had no problem with but not working right now either.

I thought it is because this time I am grouping by only one column however when I groupby two columns it still doesn't work. I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 5):

Method [`GroupBy.count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.count.html)  is used for get counts with exclude missing values, so is necessary specify column after `groupby` for check column(s) of missing values, so e.g. here is tested `hour`:

```
df = df.groupby(["hour", "location"])['hour'].count().unstack(fill_value=0).stack()
```

But if omit column after `groupby` this method use all another columns for count. So if use:

```
print (df.groupby(["hour"]).count())
      location
hour          
1            1
2            2
3            2
6            3
```

there is another column `location`, so it use it for count.

If use:

```
print (df.groupby(["location"]).count())
          hour
location      
a            2
b            2
c            4
```

there is another column `hour`, so it use it for count.

---

But if only 2 columns `DataFrame`, then is necessary specify column for avoid empty `DataFrame`, but it also depends of [pandas version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32307259/2901002):

```
print (df.groupby(["hour", "location"]).count())
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [(1, a), (2, a), (2, b), (3, b), (3, c), (6, c)]

print (df.groupby(["hour", "location"])['hour'].count())
hour  location
1     a           1
2     a           1
      b           1
3     b           1
      c           1
6     c           3
Name: hour, dtype: int64
```

---

If dont care about missing values is used method [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html), it not tested missing values, so no column after `groupby` is necessary:

```
df = df.groupby(["hour", "location"]).size().unstack(fill_value=0).stack()
```

---

```
print (df)
hour  location
1     a           1
      b           0
      c           0
2     a           1
      b           1
      c           0
3     a           0
      b           1
      c           1
6     a           0
      b           0
      c           3
dtype: int64
```

Comment: What about for using only one column in groupby statement?

Comment: @Ambleu - I hope all info is in answer, if something should be added, let me know.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not fully understanding your explanation. How does it work for df.groupby(["hour"])?

Comment: @Ambleu - It used all another columns without `hour` for count, so here `location`