# pandas pivot table with parameter "columns" but no value for each category of the column

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

I'd like to apply the pd.pivot_table() to get the number of each categorical value for column 'categories'.

Here, the basic info of the dataset is as following:

```
df.info()
Data columns (total 3 columns):
location                                   2270 non-null object
time                               2270 non-null object
categories    2270 non-null object
dtypes: object(3)
```

My code:

```
table=pd.pivot_table(df,values=['categories'],
                     index=['location','time'],
                     columns=['categories'],
                     aggfunc='count',fill_value=0)
table.head()
```

Expected result is:

```
location    time    Cat1 Cat2
L1      Jan-2020    5   1
L1      Feb-2020    2   1
L2      Jan-2019    4   3
L2      Feb-2020    5   0
```

But my result is:

```
    location      time  
    L1      Jan-2020    
    L1      Feb-2020    
    L2      Jan-2019    
    L2      Feb-2020
```

I tried to create the simple dataframe by input the data as the example below, then I could get my expected result. But if I import my whole dataframe from csv file, it failed.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html

Thanks for all the suggestions and help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) function for count and also `values` parameter should be omit:

```
table=pd.pivot_table(df,
                     index=['location','time'],
                     columns=['categories'],
                     aggfunc='size',fill_value=0)
print (table.head())
categories         Cat1  Cat2
location time                
L1       Feb-2020     2     1
         Jan-2020     5     1
L2       Feb-2020     5     0
         Jan-2019     4     3
```

Comment: but I am wondering why the example from official guide works, while my solution doesn't work?

Comment: @Elaine - Problem is with number of columns, here are only 3 columns. I think it is bug, similar problem is with `groupby` and `count` like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32307259/2901002)

Comment: very clear explanation. Thanks again for your answer