# How to convert Pandas Groupby result to Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have used the groupby method on a Pandas Dataframe and I want to convert the result to a DataFrame. I have used `unstack` but it only converts the results to features and not a proper dataframe.

I have tried approaches answered in other SO Questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10373660/converting-a-pandas-groupby-output-from-series-to-dataframe) but it was not useful.

**Original DataFrame - badges**

```
UserId      Class   
-1      |   B
-1      |   B
1       |   A   
100     |   A   
100     |   B
102     |   B   
102     |   B
107     |   A
```

**Code**
`badges = badges.groupby('UserId')['Class'].value_counts().unstack().fillna(0)`

**Output**

```
Class        A  |  B    
UserId          
-1      |   0.0 | 2.0   
1       |   1.0 | 0.0   
100     |   1.0 | 1.0   
102     |   0.0 | 2.0   
107     |   1.0 | 0.0
```

**Required Output**

```
UserId  |    A  |  B
    
-1      |   0.0 | 2.0   
1       |   1.0 | 0.0   
100     |   1.0 | 1.0   
102     |   0.0 | 2.0   
107     |   1.0 | 0.0
```

Comment: can you share the dataset?

Comment: after you do the groupby , try `badges.rename_axis(None,axis=1).reset_index()`

Comment: I have added the dataset @SoumendraMishra

Comment: @anky your code did not work. And I want `UserId` to be a feature not index.

Comment: @IshanDutta it did work for me , `badges = badges.groupby('UserId')['Class'].value_counts().unstack().fillna(0).rename_axis(None,axis=1).reset_index()`