# pandas groupby filter groups based on multiple size constraints

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby, python-3.8

I have the following code to filter out groups with size less than 4 and greater than 51.  I am issuing two statements for the same, which I believe is very inefficient. Is there a way I can say 51 > 'size' > 4

```
df = df[df.groupby('id',sort=False)['id'].transform('size') > 4]
df = df[df.groupby('id')['id'].transform('size') < 51]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html) with `inclusive=False`:

```
df[df.groupby('id',sort=False)['id'].transform('size').between(4, 51, inclusive=False)]
```

Comment: I am curious. You are not Wes McKinney right ?

Comment: @Shew - No, I am not Wes. Here are 2 answers from him and me [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10373660/).

Comment: man, great. I was thinking about a pandas book. i am gonna wait till your book comes out.