# How to convert GroupBy object in pandas to multiindexed dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a raw dataframe that looks like

```
        codcet  placa_encoded   date   time_seconds velocidade
5031 490191222  431.0      2021-03-11   70079.0      51
5032 490221211  431.0      2021-03-11   72219.0      55
7991 490361213  562.0      2021-03-11   28559.0      24
7992 490361232  562.0      2021-03-11   29102.0      29              
7993 490361221  562.0      2021-03-11   30183.0      33                 
...
```

Where the numbers on the far left are indexes from the original dataset.
My goal is to convert this into a dataframe indexed by `placa_encoded` and by `n`, a counter within each group that then looks like

```
placa_encoded  n    time_seconds  velocidade            codcet    
431.0          0      70079.0           51              490191222   
431.0          1      72219.0           55              490221211   
562.0          0      28559.0           24              490361213   
562.0          1      29102.0           29              490361232
562.0          2      30183.0           33              490361221
```

That is, I aim to `groupby('placa_encoded')` then add another column `n` that counts the position within each group. The row should be indexed by both `placa_encoded` and `n`. I think I can use `cumcount()` to do this but it's unclear to me how to add it as a column since `groupby` doesn't product a dataframe I can assign to. I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10373660/converting-a-pandas-groupby-output-from-series-to-dataframe) question but it seems they use `.count()` to convert it to a dataframe, and I want to preserve the data instead of getting any counts. I also tried to use `pd.DataFrame(gbplaca)` and `pd.DataFrame(gbplaca.groups)` to no avail.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are wanting

```
df['n'] = df.sort_values(['time_seconds'], ascending=True).groupby(['placa_encoded']).cumcount()
df = df.set_index(['placa_encoded', 'n'])
df
```

This is a multi-index with 'placa_encoded' and 'n'

Comment: I updated my answer to make it a multi-index. Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: Yes, thanks! In general, should we always operate on the original dataframe and use `groupby.agg()` type methods to create new columns we can add to the original dataframe? What if I had wanted to make a dataframe where the rows were grouped by/clumped by, say, `velocidade`, instead?

Comment: Its difficult to say as that is kind of a general question, every situation is different so its outside the bounds of a SO comment (not trying to be evasive just a kind of big question) in this situation though if you wanted to do `velocidade` instead you would just replace the `placa_encoded'` from the code above...does that answer your question (or at least sort of)

Comment: Well, the original dataframe already has rows grouped by `placa_encoded`, but not by `velocidad`. That's what I'm asking -- how would we have done the same if the dataframe wasn't grouped by `placa_encoded`. We can't just run `groupby('placa_encoded')` then the same commands, because `groupby` doesn't return a dataframe we can run `set_index` on, but instead a `DataFrameGroupBy` object.

Comment: Oh so you got a dataframe doing a groupby on `velocidad` then from that dataframe you did another group by using `placa_encoded`?

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is to set the column in `df` (named `'n'`) with the result from `df.groupby('placa_encoded').cumcount()`:

```
    df.loc[:, 'n'] = df.groupby('placa_encoded').cumcount()
    print(df)
           codcet  placa_encoded        date  time_seconds  velocidade  n
     0  490191222          431.0  2021-03-11       70079.0          51  0
     1  490221211          431.0  2021-03-11       72219.0          55  1
     2  490361213          562.0  2021-03-11       28559.0          24  0
     3  490361232          562.0  2021-03-11       29102.0          29  1
     4  490361221          562.0  2021-03-11       30183.0          33  2
```

Then, you can set the multi-index of `df` to `['placa_encoded', 'n']` if you want:

```
    df = df.set_index(['placa_encoded', 'index'])
    print(df)
                         codcet        date  time_seconds  velocidade
     placa_encoded n                                                 
     431.0         0  490191222  2021-03-11       70079.0          51
                   1  490221211  2021-03-11       72219.0          55
     562.0         0  490361213  2021-03-11       28559.0          24
                   1  490361232  2021-03-11       29102.0          29
                   2  490361221  2021-03-11       30183.0          33
```