# as_index=False groupBy doesn't work with count

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

When I run groupby on a dataframe with as_index set to False, count seems to not work at all. For example,

```py
import pandas as pd

word_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'c', 'c', 'b', 'a', 'c']

df = pd.DataFrame(word_list, columns=['word'])
as_counts = df.groupby('word', as_index=False).count()
print(as_counts)
```

```py
  word
0    a
1    b
2    c
```

If you try the same with `.size()` as in

```py
as_counts = df.groupby('word', as_index=False).size()
```

it works as expected

```py
  word  size
0    a     3
1    b     2
2    c     4
```

What difference between the two functions explains this difference in output?

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10373660/converting-a-pandas-groupby-multiindex-output-from-series-back-to-dataframe) is asking a different question entirely as, in this case, the frame is neither MultiIndex nor seeking to maintain non-unique indices. Equally, none of the answers in that post address the problem of this question.

Comment: @jezrael But that does not answer the question at heart which is "What difference between the two functions explains this difference in output?" I'd also point out that any person facing the same issue as this, in doing due dilligence, would not find that question and then the specific one-liner (addressed to a different scenario) that just happens to work.

Comment: OK, agree, so reopened.

Comment: Since the question is no duplicate might accept an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`groupby.count`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.count.html) is designed to work on the columns other than the grouping columns while [`groupby.size`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.size.html) is designed to output **a single** new column (named size), irrespective of the number of existing columns.

This makes sense since `count` depends on the NA status, while **`size` is always constant** within a group (the number of rows, irrespective of the values).

This can easily be seen by adding several dummy columns:

```
df.assign(dummy1=1, dummy2=None).groupby('word', as_index=False).count()

# as many output columns as the input columns (minus grouper)
# only the non NA values are counted
  word  dummy1  dummy2
0    a       3       0
1    b       2       0
2    c       4       0
```

VS:

```
df.assign(dummy1=1, dummy2=None).groupby('word', as_index=False).size()

# grouper columns + ONE "size" column
  word  size
0    a     3
1    b     2
2    c     4
```

This is actually explicitly stated in the documentation:

> DataFrameGroupBy.size()
>
> Returns:
>
> DataFrame or Series
>
> Number of rows in each group **as a Series if as_index is True or a DataFrame if as_index is False.**

So back to your original example, `groupby.counts` outputs nothing since there are no columns to use (the grouping columns are excluded from the aggregation unless specifically sliced from the DataFrameGroupBy object).

---

###### workaround

As noted elsewhere, the workaround if you want to count one of the grouping columns is to explicitly slice it:

```
df.groupby('word', as_index=False)['word'].count()

   word
0     3
1     2
2     4
```

Amusingly, you can slice it more than once and get as many columns in the output:

```
df.groupby('word', as_index=False)[['word', 'word']].count()

   word  word
0     3     3
1     2     2
2     4     4
```

Answer (score 2):

This is nothing to do with `as_index=False`.
To use `count` you need a value that can be counted.
Adding another column will help:

```
df['cnt'] = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

slightly change your groupby for count to this:

```
import pandas as pd

word_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'c', 'c', 'b', 'a', 'c']

df = pd.DataFrame(word_list, columns=['word'])
as_counts = df.groupby("word")["word"].count()
as_counts
```

output:

```
a    3
b    2
c    4
```